# How to define a screen-size specific animation in XML

Tags: android, android-animation

I created an `Animation` for the `Fragments` in my application. The `Animation` animates moving between tabs, for that purpose I need to animate the current `Fragment` to move completely off screen while the need `Fragment` slides in from the opposite side. Kind of like the `Animation` the `ViewPager` uses.

I need to specify an absolute starting and ending position of the `View` and since different devices have different dimensions I cannot define an `Animation` in XML that fits all devices. On a bigger device the `View` might not slide of screen completely and on a smaller device the `View` moves to much and continues moving when he is already off screen.

So I guess my question is: How can I define an animation in XML which will slide a `Fragment` off screen and at the same time fit on all devices?

My animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">      

  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:propertyName="x" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueTo="720" 
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:duration="300"/>  

</set>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## 1) Regarding the bounty:

> [**Existing answers on SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments) suggest subclassing the FrameLayout...

If you want to use an `ObjectAnimator` you have no choice but to subclass the `View` you want to animate.  You need to provide the `ObjectAnimator` with the necessary getter and setter methods to do its magic as it essentially just calls those getter and setter methods to perform the `Animation`.

The question you are linking to (**[Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)**) is subclassing `FrameLayout` to add a `setXFraction()` and a `getXFraction()` method. They are implemented in a way to set the x value relative to the width of the `FrameLayout`. Only by doing this can the `ObjectAnimator` do anything else besides animating between absolute values.

So to summarise, the `ObjectAnimator` itself doesn't actually do much animating, it just calls getter and setter methods through reflection.

> Is there really no way to get the actual screen pixel dimensions (not
>   just dp) into the xml file?

With an `ObjectAnimator` there is no way to achieve that. `ObjectAnimators` just interpolate from  a start value to and end value. As I explained above, the setter method defines what actually happens.

> For example, calling a custom function that returns the width would be
>   fine, or defining a constant that code can set, having code set said
>   constant to equal the screen width, then accessing that constant from
>   the xml would be equally useful.

You cannot insert any value from code into any xml resource. Everything contained in your xml files is compiled into your APK when you build it and **cannot** be changed at runtime. And that is also an answer to your other question: There is no resource or constant or anything which would be accessible in xml which contains the current screen size. Dynamic values like the screen size of the device the app is installed on cannot be a part of those resources since everything in them is compiled into your app when you build it.

---

## 2) Possible Solution: View Animations

One possible solution is to use view animations instead of an `ObjectAnimator`. With view animations you can specify fractions instead of just absolute values:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

This would animate a `View` from `-100%` to `0%` of the screen height. In other words from completely of the screen to the position of the `View`. You can use it like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

I realise that this might not be of any help to you. There are cases in which one has to use `ObjectAnimators` and cannot use view animations. But as long as you are able to use view animations this should pretty much solve your problem.

- [**Link to
  documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)
- [**Related question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766034/2310866)

---

## 3) Best practice

What we really should be addressing here is what I think is a misconception on your part. As you already noticed every animation you define in xml has absolute start and end values. Those values are static and cannot be changed after compiling your app.

If you look at how the resources work with the many available selectors and also with dp, sp... then you will realise that it is designed to do one thing:
You can for example define an animation that moves a `View` by 100dp. Dp is a measurement of physical size, 100dp will be the exact same physical size one any screen with any pixel density. Through selectors you could alter this animation for devices with smaller or bigger screens where the animation may be moving the `View` too much or too little. But you can only fill in static values. Aside from working with selectors you cannot customise the animation for each device.

So you see, the resources are really just designed for anything that's static and unchanging. It works great for dimensions or string translations but sometimes with animations it can be a bit of a pain. As I said above only view animations provide a way around the static nature by providing the option of specifying fractions instead of absolute values. But in general you cannot define anything dynamic in xml.

To futher corroborate this argument look at Google's excellent DevBytes videos about animation:

- [**View Animations**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UWXqFBF86U)
- [**Custom Activity Animations**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA)
- [**Cardflip Animation**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMcu35-tVls)
- [**Property Animations**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UbJhmkeSig)
- [**ListView Animations**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs)

Then you will notice that not a single animation in those examples is ever defined in xml. Sure one could argue that they don't define them in xml because they want to have an easier time explaining and showing the code, but in my opinion this once again proves one point:

**You cannot define an animation in static resources which depends on a purely dynamic value**

Since the screen width/height will be different from device to device you need different animations for each device. Only view animations provide a way around that since they allow you to define fractions instead of absolute values. In any other case you are going to need to define the animations programmatically. Fortunately that's not difficult with `ObjectAnimators`:

```
Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, startValue, endValue);
animator.start();
```

This would animate the x position of the `View` from the start to the end value in pixels. You can pass in the width of the `View` to animate it like you want to:

```
Animator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, -view.getWidth(), 0.0f);
animator.start();
```

This would animate the `View` to slide in from the left. It starts completely off screen and stops in its final position. You could also just do this:

```
view.animate().x(targetValue);
```

This would animate the `View` from its current x position to the target x value.

But please don't misunderstand me, you should still try to define as much as possible - be it animations or anything else - in the resources. Hardcoding animations or any other value should be avoided as much as possible, unless it's necessary like in your case.

---

## 4) Summary

So to summarise:

- You cannot do what you want to do with `ObjectAnimators` without adding the getter and setter methods you need to the `View` you want to animate.
- If possible use [**view animations**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html). With them you can define animations based on fractions of the width or height of the `View`.
- If the above doesn't work or is not applicable to your situation then define the animations [**programmatically**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator), this will work in any case.

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the terrific answer.  I guess the big limitation is that the only way I can see to add any animation to a FragmentTransaction is with setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit).  And that API appears to expect an Animator resource ID, not an Animation resource ID.  Defining my Animator in code is no problem.  But then can I give it a resource ID?

Comment: OK, problem solved, I create my code animator in the Fragment's onCreateAnimator method.

Comment: I just now wanted to tell you about `onCreateAnimator()`, guess you figured it out on your own. I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

just create different folders based on screen densities.

so lets say your xml for animation is in a folder called anim  (in res parent folder).

then create anim-ldpi , anim-mdpi , etc in res as well.  Put your respective animation in each of these folders which represent screen density and android will select the right one.

Comment: is the answer acceptable for you ? Please comment or accept.

Comment: `anim-ldpi`, `anim-mdpi` and so on are variants on screen _density_, not screen size.

Comment: The above answer does the trick! I had two screen densities hdpi and xhdpi and the %p specified in toYDelta of <translate> had to be changed for respective screen. Keeping two copies in anim-hdpi and anim-xhdpi of xml file and changing the %p of toYDelta in respective files did the trick! Thanx a lot @j2emanue!

Answer (score 0):

Somebody was asking for my working solution. Here it is. It is C# code via Mono. Hopefully Java authors can figure out what it should be in that language.

```
public class MyFragment: Fragment  {

    public int TransitDuration {
      get {
        return 500;
      }
    }

    public override Animator OnCreateAnimator(FragmentTransit transit, bool enter, int nextAnim) {
      switch (transit) {
        case FragmentTransit.FragmentOpen:
          {
            if (enter) {
              return this.EnterFromLeftAnimator;
            } else {
              return this.ExitToRightAnimator;
            }
          }
        case FragmentTransit.FragmentClose:
          {
            if (enter) {
              return this.EnterFromRightAnimator;
            } else {
              return this.ExitToLeftAnimator;
            }
          }
        default:
          Animator r = base.OnCreateAnimator(transit, enter, nextAnim);
          if (r == null) {
            if (!this.IsAdded) {
              this.OnContextHidden();
            }
          }
          return r;
      }
    }


    public Animator EnterFromLeftAnimator {
      get {
        float width = Screen.MainScreen.PixelSize.Width; // this is an object of mine; other code cached the width there long ago. It would actually be better to use the window width.
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(this, "X", width, 0);
        animator.SetDuration(this.TransitDuration);
        Animator r = animator as Animator;
        return r;
      }
    }
    public Animator ExitToRightAnimator {
      get {
        float width = Screen.MainScreen.PixelSize.Width;
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(this, "X", 0, -width);
        animator.SetDuration(this.TransitDuration);
        Animator r = animator as Animator;
        r.AddListener(new AnimatorEndListenerAdapter(() => this.OnContextHidden()));
        return r;
      }
    }
    public Animator EnterFromRightAnimator {
      get {
        float width = this.ScreenWidth;
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(this, "X", -width, 0);
        animator.SetDuration(this.TransitDuration);
        Animator r = animator as Animator;
        return r;
      }
    }
    public Animator ExitToLeftAnimator {
      get {
        float width = this.ScreenWidth;
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(this, "X", 0, width);
        animator.SetDuration(this.TransitDuration);
        Animator r = animator as Animator;
        r.AddListener(new AnimatorEndListenerAdapter(() => this.OnContextHidden()));

        return r;
      }
    }

    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
      this.RetainInstance = true;
    }

}
```