# Show and hide a View with a slide up/down animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a `LinearLayout` that I want to show or hide with an `Animation` that pushes the layout upwards or downwards whenever I change its visibility.

I've seen a few samples out there but none of them suit my needs.

I have created two xml files for the animations but I do not know how to start them when I change the visibility of a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 727, accepted):

With the new animation API that was introduced in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) it is very simple to create such animations.

Sliding a `View` down by a distance:

```
view.animate().translationY(distance);
```

You can later slide the `View` back to its original position like this:

```
view.animate().translationY(0);
```

---

You can also easily combine multiple animations. The following animation will slide a `View` down by its height and fade it in at the same time:

```
// Prepare the View for the animation
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setAlpha(0.0f);

// Start the animation
view.animate()
    .translationY(view.getHeight())
    .alpha(1.0f)
    .setListener(null);
```

You can then fade the `View` back out and slide it back to its original position. We also set an `AnimatorListener` so we can set the visibility of the `View` back to `GONE` once the animation is finished:

```
view.animate()
    .translationY(0)
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: why view not visible once it gone?

Comment: @Ram You mean why is a `View` not drawn on the screen when you set its visibility to `View.GONE`?

Comment: i want to animate view when visible and when gone. but if i first gone view  .it not able to visible and place of view is blank

Comment: @Ram What are you trying to achieve by animating a `View` when its visibility is set to `View.GONE`? If you set its visibility to anything besides `View.VISIBLE` then the `View` will not be visible. I don't understand what you are asking. If you want your animation to be visible then don't set the visibility of the `View` to `View.GONE`.

Comment: thanks it work when i removed view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @Xaver, same issue here not working even after removing view.SetVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: @PKR what kind of answer do you expect from me now? You are doing something wrong. But without having even the slightest bit of information I can't help you.

Comment: facing same issue what Ram was facing, at first time it works fine but from next time when i make that view in gone state and try to make that view visible again it doesn't appear.

Comment: @PKR Just ask a question. Include all the relevant code and describe the exact problem and what you have tried so far. If you do that you will surely get a proper answer.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I think the problem many have is that the listener `onAnimationEnd` is called every time for a multi-occurring animation, which means that `onAnimationEnd` is called also when the view get shown, which sets its visibility to Gone, etc.

Comment: How do I solve the issue of not being visible again on 2nd time?

Comment: @Vincent_Paing What are you talking about?

Comment: View is visible once, and then on next time after it's have been animated to gone. It's not visible only for a short time, I've tried setListener(null) to remove existing listeners but it doesn't work either

Comment: @Vincent_Paing Are you setting the `View` to `View.VISIBLE` again?

Comment: Yes, set VISIBLE and then play the slide in animation again cause it to become GONE

Comment: Great answer. How would one combine this with ScrollView? So that when panel moves beyond boundaries, I could scroll down ? Thanx.

Comment: @Sermilion You are probably going to find your answer by googling around a bit, otherwise ask a new question. But if you ask a new question don't forget to show what you tried so far...

Comment: I figured it. I set a view below with height that of sliding view and set its visibility to "gone". When I animate, I make visibility visible and ScrollViw takes care of the rest. Seems like a hack but it works as needed)

Comment: `setListener(null)` when you want to make it visible again after once it gets gone.

Comment: To everyone that are stuck with the issue of the view not being visible after it's gone, @XaverKapeller 's animation sets the view's `alpha` of zero, you must set the `alpha` and the `translation` of the view back to 1 and 0 respectively after the GONE animation in order to show the view afterwards.

Comment: answer should be structured so anyone use answer as method directly without any doubt.

Comment: For people who had a problem getting the view to show after the first time, if your show/hide view is initialized in the hide position, when you do the first animation, `view.getHeight()` will return 0 since the view is GONE. To fix this, change the show Y translation from `view.getHeight()` to 0, and the hide Y translation from 0 to -1 * `view.getHeight()`.

Answer (score 187):

I was having troubles understanding an applying the accepted answer. I needed a little more context. Now that I have figured it out, here is a full example:

[image]

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button myButton;
    View myView;
    boolean isUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

        // initialize as invisible (could also do in xml)
        myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        myButton.setText("Slide up");
        isUp = false;
    }

    // slide the view from below itself to the current position
    public void slideUp(View view){
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                0,                 // fromXDelta
                0,                 // toXDelta
                view.getHeight(),  // fromYDelta
                0);                // toYDelta
        animate.setDuration(500);
        animate.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(animate);
    }

    // slide the view from its current position to below itself
    public void slideDown(View view){
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
                0,                 // fromXDelta
                0,                 // toXDelta
                0,                 // fromYDelta
                view.getHeight()); // toYDelta
        animate.setDuration(500);
        animate.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(animate);
    }

    public void onSlideViewButtonClick(View view) {
        if (isUp) {
            slideDown(myView);
            myButton.setText("Slide up");
        } else {
            slideUp(myView);
            myButton.setText("Slide down");
        }
        isUp = !isUp;
    }
}
```

*activity_mail.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.slideview.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:onClick="onSlideViewButtonClick"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:background="#a6e1aa"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Notes

- Thanks to [this article](https://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/simple-android-animation-on-view-gonevisible/) for pointing me in the right direction. It was more helpful than the other answers on this page.
- If you want to start with the view on screen, then don't initialize it as `INVISIBLE`.
- Since we are animating it completely off screen, there is no need to set it back to `INVISIBLE`. If you are not animating completely off screen, though, then you can add an alpha animation and set the visibility with an `AnimatorListenerAdapter`.
- [Property Animation docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Comment: android:visibility="invisible" to initialise the view animation as a  hide

Comment: I don't recommend use of  animate.setFillAfter(true);
if you have clickable views under the slided view it will not recive events

Comment: Notice that without `.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` the slide up function won't work as visually expected.

Comment: `Translate Animation` moves the view. If you want to animate view like its scaling itself then use `ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 0, 1)`

Comment: Note that `TranslateAnimation` won't move clickables if they are present in your view. It will just move pixels. This can be unexpected in most cases. Refer this to move clickables as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631361/5353128

Answer (score 98):

Now visibility change animations should be done via `Transition API` which available in support (androidx) package. Just call [TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup,%20androidx.transition.Transition)) method with [Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zkQT.gif) transition then change visibility of the view.

[image]

```
import androidx.transition.Slide;
import androidx.transition.Transition;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;

private void toggle(boolean show) {
    View redLayout = findViewById(R.id.redLayout);
    ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);

    Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    transition.setDuration(600);
    transition.addTarget(R.id.redLayout);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
    redLayout.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="play" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/redLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="#5f00"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648103/1372866) with another default and custom transition examples.

Comment: @akubi yeah, it should be

Comment: One of the best and easy answers! Thanks!

Comment: just to note, this requires `minSdkVersion 21`

Comment: @lasec0203  no, classes are from `androidx` package. It works fine on pre 21 api.

Comment: :thumbs_up: this got rid of a method ambiguity error I was getting

Comment: this is the best solution. Neat and clean :) thank you so much

Comment: This solution has issues. Some of the animations don't work on API 29+
https://stackoverflow.com/q/65547260/11110509

Comment: thumbs up, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Hi is there a way to animate 2 views simultaneously on the same root? I read the documentation that TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition only let you to animate 1 view at a time at the same root

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE this solution works fine. The issue must be something not related to the Transition API.

Answer (score 52):

Easiest solution: set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on the container holding your views.

To put it into some context: If you have a layout like below, all visibility changes to the views in this container will be animated automatically.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >

    <Views_which_change_visibility>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can find more details about this on [Animating Layout Changes - Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html)

Comment: It is the easiest but it's behavior differs due to phone manufacturer and he's code changes

Comment: This animates the alpha, not the position.

Comment: Yes, but that's what the original question was about if I understood it correctly. If you want to animate positions, you could use a RecyclerView that uses ViewHolders with stable ids.

Comment: in case it didn't work in nested views refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649918/6039240

Answer (score 24):

**Kotlin**

Based on [Suragch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3681880/suragch)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46644736/2122149), here is an elegant way using View extension:

```
fun View.slideUp(duration: Int = 500) {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, this.height.toFloat(), 0f)
    animate.duration = duration.toLong()
    animate.fillAfter = true
    this.startAnimation(animate)
}

fun View.slideDown(duration: Int = 500) {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, this.height.toFloat())
    animate.duration = duration.toLong()
    animate.fillAfter = true
    this.startAnimation(animate)
}
```

And then wherever you want to use it, you just need `myView.slideUp()` or `myView.slideDown()`

Comment: Only bug is, it doesn't need "fillAfter=true" as it block child views click accessibility

Comment: Also You would probably need to add a listener to slideDown animation and make view gone onAnimationEnd.

Answer (score 12):

You can start the correct `Animation` when the visibility of the `LinearLayout` changes by creating a new subclass of `LinearLayout` and overriding `setVisibility()` to start the `Animations`. Consider something like this:

```
public class SimpleViewAnimator extends LinearLayout
{
    private Animation inAnimation;
    private Animation outAnimation;

    public SimpleViewAnimator(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setInAnimation(Animation inAnimation)
    {
        this.inAnimation = inAnimation;
    }

    public void setOutAnimation(Animation outAnimation)
    {
        this.outAnimation = outAnimation;
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility)
    {
        if (getVisibility() != visibility)
        {
            if (visibility == VISIBLE)
            {
                if (inAnimation != null) startAnimation(inAnimation);
            }
            else if ((visibility == INVISIBLE) || (visibility == GONE))
            {
                if (outAnimation != null) startAnimation(outAnimation);
            }
        }

        super.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually like better the subclass approach. Thank you very much.

Comment: This, is an awesome solution that I'm gonna implement in my BaseView. Thx for this!

Comment: As this works when showing, when hiding, the view disappears before the animation can be seen. Any workarounds?

Comment: @BramVandenbussche This is a terrible solution. It makes the `View` responsible for its own animations which is **NEVER** what you want. Imagine you want to animate the `View` differently in another part of your app. What do you do then? Add a flag to not automatically animate the visibility? Subclass the `View` and override `setVisibility()` to remove the animation? Or even worse implement `setVisibility()` with another animation?  It just gets uglier and uglier from there. Don't use this "solution".

Comment: Better call it AnimatedLinearLayout

Comment: This is really nice. The way I had my layout set up already was just toggling visible/invisible, and this is the easiest way to add animation without changing too much.

Comment: @McAdam331 No. The easiest way to add animation is just to add the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` attribute to your layout xml and then android will animate your appearing and disappearing `Views` automatically.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (filter_section.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
    filter_section.animate()
            .translationY(filter_section.getHeight()).alpha(1.0f)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                    filter_section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    filter_section.setAlpha(0.0f);
                }
            });
} else {
    filter_section.animate()
            .translationY(0).alpha(0.0f)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    filter_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Issues with this answer: 1) Terrible code formatting. 2) You use a code snippet to post code which actually cannot be run in the browser. This doesn't just add two useless buttons, but it also destroys syntax highlighting. 3) It's just some random code dump without any explanation or purpose. 4) You are changing the visibility while performing an animation. Aside from the fact that this is obvious code smell this will also not work properly. Changing visibility starts a new layouting process, only after that is finished the animation actually has values to work with. The list goes on and on...

Comment: I have already edited your answer to fix formatting and turned the code snippet into an actual code block. But you have to fill in the rest...

Comment: Sorry got it mate, i made up the code from yours because it doesn't work well for me ,this code of mine works.but changes needed in the way of posting i agree .

Comment: @AmeenMaheen What is `setAlpha` for?

Comment: @ Igor Ganapolsky it is used for transparency ie to give a fading effect

Answer (score 7):

you can slide up and down any view or layout by using bellow code in android app

```
boolean isClicked = false;
LinearLayout mLayoutTab = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

if(isClicked) {
    isClicked = false;
    mLayoutTab.animate()
        .translationYBy(120)
        .translationY(0)     
        .setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
} else {
    isClicked = true;
    mLayoutTab.animate()
         .translationYBy(0)
         .translationY(120)
         .setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
}
```

Comment: what is 120? and what is 0? what's the unit for setDuration if I want to hardcode this?

Comment: here 120 and 0 is the distance related to Y axis if you put hard code than getting problem in large screen or tablet so, you need to put value from your string.xml value for all the different device. and duration is the time you want to show animation of layout....!!! sorry for my poor English...!

Comment: @varotariyavajsi This doesn't actually show/hide the visibility of a view.

Comment: hello igor ganapolsky i know these...it is just translate view in y direction, if user need to show up and down like a bottom slider it will be working fine.

Answer (score 6):

Using ObjectAnimator

```
private fun slideDown(view: View) {
    val height = view.height
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0f, height.toFloat()).apply {
        duration = 1000
        start()
    }
}

private fun slideUp(view: View) {
    val height = view.height
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_Y, height.toFloat(), 0f)).apply {
        duration = 1000
        start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor improvments:  We can use constant View.TRANSLATION_Y instead of "translationY" and also in the slide up ObjectAnimation we can do .apply { doOnEnd { view.visibility = View.GONE } .......}.start()

Comment: `0.toFloat()` can also just be `0f`

Answer (score 4):

Use this class:

```
public class ExpandCollapseExtention {

 public static void expand(View view) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(view, 0, view.getMeasuredHeight());
    mAnimator.start();
}


public static void collapse(final View view) {
    int finalHeight = view.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(view, finalHeight, 0);

    mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {               
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    mAnimator.start();
}


private static ValueAnimator slideAnimator(final View v, int start, int end) {

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = v.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    return animator;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a corner case where my view's height was still `zero` so...

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.view.View;

public final class AnimationUtils {

  public static void slideDown(final View view) {
        view.animate()
                .translationY(view.getHeight())
                .alpha(0.f)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        // superfluous restoration
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        view.setAlpha(1.f);
                        view.setTranslationY(0.f);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void slideUp(final View view) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.setAlpha(0.f);

        if (view.getHeight() > 0) {
            slideUpNow(view);
        } else {
            // wait till height is measured
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    slideUpNow(view);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static void slideUpNow(final View view) {
        view.setTranslationY(view.getHeight());
        view.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .alpha(1.f)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        view.setAlpha(1.f);
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

With Kotlin extensions you can use this:

```
enum class SlideDirection{
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}

enum class SlideType{
    SHOW,
    HIDE
}

fun View.slideAnimation(direction: SlideDirection, type: SlideType, duration: Long = 250){
    val fromX: Float
    val toX: Float
    val fromY: Float
    val toY: Float
    val array = IntArray(2)
    getLocationInWindow(array)
    if((type == SlideType.HIDE && (direction == SlideDirection.RIGHT || direction == SlideDirection.DOWN)) ||
        (type == SlideType.SHOW && (direction == SlideDirection.LEFT || direction == SlideDirection.UP))   ){
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        val windowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        val deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
        array[0] = deviceWidth
        array[1] = deviceHeight
    }
    when (direction) {
        SlideDirection.UP -> {
            fromX = 0f
            toX = 0f
            fromY = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) 0f else (array[1] + height).toFloat()
            toY = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) -1f * (array[1] + height)  else 0f
        }
        SlideDirection.DOWN -> {
            fromX = 0f
            toX = 0f
            fromY = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) 0f else -1f * (array[1] + height)
            toY = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) 1f * (array[1] + height)  else 0f
        }
        SlideDirection.LEFT -> {
            fromX = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) 0f else 1f * (array[0] + width)
            toX = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) -1f * (array[0] + width) else 0f
            fromY = 0f
            toY = 0f
        }
        SlideDirection.RIGHT -> {
            fromX = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) 0f else -1f * (array[0] + width)
            toX = if(type == SlideType.HIDE) 1f * (array[0] + width) else 0f
            fromY = 0f
            toY = 0f
        }
    }
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(
        fromX,
        toX,
        fromY,
        toY
    )
    animate.duration = duration
    animate.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener{
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {

        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            if(type == SlideType.HIDE){
                visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    })
    startAnimation(animate)
}
```

Example for the extension:

```
view.slideAnimation(SlideDirection.UP, SlideType.HIDE)//to make it disappear through top of the screen
view.slideAnimation(SlideDirection.DOWN, SlideType.SHOW)//to make it reappear from top of the screen

view.slideAnimation(SlideDirection.DOWN, SlideType.HIDE)//to make it disappear through bottom of the screen
view.slideAnimation(SlideDirection.UP, SlideType.SHOW)//to make it reappear from bottom of the screen
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show/hide many views together with `Transition`, you can can use `TransitionSet` (because you can not play 2 "single" `Transition` together)

```
fun slideTopBottomVisibility(topLayout: View, bottomLayout: View, show: Boolean) {
    val topTransition: Transition = Slide(Gravity.TOP)
    topTransition.duration = 600
    topTransition.addTarget(topLayout)

    val bottomTransition: Transition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
    bottomTransition.duration = 600
    bottomTransition.addTarget(bottomLayout)

    val transitionSet = TransitionSet()
    transitionSet.addTransition(topTransition)
    transitionSet.addTransition(bottomTransition)

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(topLayout.parent as ViewGroup, transitionSet)
    topLayout.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    bottomLayout.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can used the simple three lines of code to show the animation...

```
//getting the hiding view by animation

 mbinding.butn.setOnClickListener {

                val SlideOutLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                simplelayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                simplelayout.startAnimation(SlideOutLeft)


                val SlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(applicationContext, R.anim.slide_in_right)
                animation1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                animation1.startAnimation(SlideInRight)

            }
            //again unhide the view animation
            mbinding.buttn.setOnClickListener {


               val SlideInLeft=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in_left)
                //set the layout
               simplelayout.visibility=View.VISIBLE
               simplelayout.startAnimation(SlideInLeft)

               val SlideOutRight=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_out_right)
               animation1.visibility=View.INVISIBLE
               animation1.startAnimation(SlideOutRight)

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Just get a reference to your view and call this method:

```
public static void animateViewFromBottomToTop(final View view){

    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            final int TRANSLATION_Y = view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(TRANSLATION_Y);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.animate()
                .translationYBy(-TRANSLATION_Y)
                .setDuration(500)
                .setStartDelay(200)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(final Animator animation) {

                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                })
                .start();
        }
    });
}
```

No need to do anything else =)

Comment: Why would you need a GlobalLayoutListener to do this? Why are you setting the visibility on such a weird way? Why are you including things like a start delay which is irrelevant to question in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

One of the simple ways:

```
containerView.setLayoutTransition(LayoutTransition())
containerView.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
```

Comment: And what else? Will there be an animation if I just set the `view.visibility = View.GONE` ???

Answer (score 1):

Suragch's answer in Kotlin. This worked for me.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var isUp: Boolean = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var myView: View = findViewById(R.id.my_view)
    var myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.my_button)

    //Initialize as invisible
    myView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    myButton.setText("Slide up")

    isUp = false

}


fun View.slideUp(duration: Int = 500){
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, this.height.toFloat(), 0f)
    animate.duration = duration.toLong()
    animate.fillAfter = true
    this.startAnimation(animate)
}

fun View.slideDown(duration: Int = 500) {
    visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val animate = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, this.height.toFloat())
    animate.duration = duration.toLong()
    animate.fillAfter = true
    this.startAnimation(animate)
}

fun onSlideViewButtonClick(view: View){
    if(isUp){
        my_view.slideDown()
        my_button.setText("Slide Up")

    }
    else{
        my_view.slideUp()
        my_button.setText("Slide Down")
    }
    isUp = !isUp
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of [ashakirov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144349/5978440) for **Kotlin** user

```
 val transition: Transition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                transition.duration = 600
                transition.addTarget(you_parent_layout_id)
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayoutId, transition)
                yourViewIdToHide.visibility = if (yourViewIdToHide.isShown) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do for multiple `Button`(In this case `ImageView`)

**MainActivity.java**

```
findViewById(R.id.arrowIV).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (strokeWidthIV.getAlpha() == 0f) {
                    findViewById(R.id.arrowIV).animate().rotationBy(180);

                    strokeWidthIV.animate().translationXBy(-120 * 4).alpha(1f);
                    findViewById(R.id.colorChooseIV).animate().translationXBy(-120 * 3).alpha(1f);
                    findViewById(R.id.saveIV).animate().translationXBy(-120 * 2).alpha(1f);
                    findViewById(R.id.clearAllIV).animate().translationXBy(-120).alpha(1f);
                } else {
                    findViewById(R.id.arrowIV).animate().rotationBy(180);

                    strokeWidthIV.animate().translationXBy(120 * 4).alpha(0f);
                    findViewById(R.id.colorChooseIV).animate().translationXBy(120 * 3).alpha(0f);
                    findViewById(R.id.saveIV).animate().translationXBy(120 * 2).alpha(0f);
                    findViewById(R.id.clearAllIV).animate().translationXBy(120).alpha(0f);
                }
            }
        });
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/strokeWidthIV"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     android:alpha="0"
     android:contentDescription="Clear All"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/colorChooseIV"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     android:alpha="0"
     android:contentDescription="Clear All"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_palette"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/saveIV"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     android:alpha="0"
     android:contentDescription="Clear All"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_save"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/clearAllIV"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     android:alpha="0"
     android:contentDescription="Clear All"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_all"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/arrowIV"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     android:contentDescription="Arrow"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer which toggles the view visibility in onClick, also flips arrow upside down, and also moves other views up smoothly when hiding the component.

```
private fun toggleRecyclerViewVisibility(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    container: FrameLayout,
    arrow: ImageView
) {
    //toggle arrow direction, also block user clicks until animation finishes.
    arrow
        .animate()
        .rotation(
            if (arrow.rotation == 0F)
                180F
            else 0F
        )
        .withStartAction { container.isClickable = false }
        .withEndAction { container.isClickable = true }
        .start()

    //toggle recyclerview visibility with animation.
    with(recyclerView) {
        var cof = -1
        var vis = View.GONE
        var alph = 0F

        if (visibility == View.GONE) {
            cof = 0
            vis = View.VISIBLE
            alph = 1F
        }
        animate()
            .translationY(height.toFloat() * cof)
            .alpha(alph)
            .withStartAction {//in case showing the recyclerview show it at the beginning.
                if (vis == View.VISIBLE)
                    visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            .withEndAction {//in case hiding the recyclerview hide it at the end.
                if (vis == View.GONE)
                    visibility = View.GONE
            }
            .start()
    }
}
```

the views looks like this

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subRootLinearView"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--other views-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundGray"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/awaitingConfirmation"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arrow_image_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--other views-->
            </LinearLayout>
```

then inside your code you add this line first, which solves `animateLayoutChanges` not working in big nested views, which basically makes other views move up smoothly when hiding the recyclerview

```
subRootLinearView.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
```

also your parent linear layout should include this attribute

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

then call the method with your views

```
 toggleRecyclerViewVisibility(
                    recycler,
                    header,
                    arrowImageView
                )
```