# animateLayoutChanges does not work well with nested layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a nested layout like the following:

```
 <LinearLayout>     <!----Parent layout--->
    <LinearLayout>    <!-----child 1--->
       ...
    </LinearLayout>   <!----child 1 ended--->
    <LinearLayout>    <!-----child 2--->
       ...
    </LinearLayout>   <!----child 2 ended--->
 </LinearLayout>    <!----Parent endded--->
```

The problem I am having now is that since all my data items are within child 1 or child 2 `Linearlayout`, if I add or delete a item the child linearlayout will animated with the effect of animateLayoutChanges but the parent layout will not do any animation. (I have `android:animateLayoutChanges` set to `true` for all linear layouts). Especially when I delete an item within child 1 the animation effect becomes weird (basically child 2 will jump up while child 1 is still doing its animation).

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Shortly after I posted this question, I found this on android developer's site in the LayoutTransition API.

> Using LayoutTransition at multiple levels of a nested view hierarchy may not work due to the interrelationship of the various levels of layout.

So does anyone have any work around suggestions for this issue?

Answer (score 98):

The `animateLayoutChanges` property makes use of `LayoutTransitions`, which animate both the layout's children and, from Android 4.0 onward, ancestors in the layout hierarchy all the way to the top of the tree. In Honeycomb, only the layout's children will be animated. See [this Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html) for details.

Unfortunately, it seems that there's currently no simple way to have the siblings of a layout react to its `LayoutTransitions`. You could try using a `TransitionListener` to get notified when the layout's bounds are being changed, and move the sibling views accordingly using Animators. See Chet Haase's second answer in [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/GATS8CkJNDZ).

**EDIT** - Turns out there *is* a way. In Android 4.1+ (API level 16+) you can use a layout transition type `CHANGING`, which is disabled by default. To enable it in code:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLayout);
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = layout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

So, in your example, to have child 2 layout animated, you'd need to enable the `CHANGING` layout transformation for it. The transformation would then be applied when there is a change in the bounds of its parent.

See [this DevBytes video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g) for more details.

Comment: I did try this and it is not really working well in my situation, I think set enableTransitionType to changing has a similar effect as set the animateLayoutChanges flag to be true. Anyway, I moved to another approach so animating nested layout is no longer needed.

Comment: @Vijju I moved away from this design and took a different approach. From the document I have read, I don't think this can be easily done so I guess you either have to build with out this small animation or write the transition yourself.

Comment: Using LayoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING) worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING); works indeed for nested layout just add it to your parent layout. however disappearing views will be out of sync you will see that when you gone a view the parent layout will finish first before the child. to fix this  you also need to modify the child layout transition and set layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0); by doing this appearing and disappearing will be in sync with parent and child.

Comment: Chen do you mind telling us which is this document you read?
I'm in a very similar situation here :)

Comment: @DanieleSegato Its the one on developer.android.com :).  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html here is the link.

Comment: This along with @chronogenre 's solution worked for me. However, I had to apply this to multiple children in  my case.

Comment: Hi. When I do enableTransitionType(int) on the parent LinearLayout, whose child I want to animate when making it (child) visible/gone, it's giving 'NullPointerException... enableTransitionType(int) on a null object reference'. Any hint?

Comment: @chronogenre setStartDelay indeed syncs between the two transitions, but the disappearing view is fading over the moving child next to it. is there a way to start the CHANGING movement after the fade out is done ?

Comment: @AbuRuqaiyah maybe you are missing `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your layout container? It was happening to me and after reading the docs it seems that if you don't set the flag then no `LayoutTransition` is instantiated.

Comment: @AsafK you can create a custom LayoutTransition and set: lt.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, null). This is solving the fading issue

Comment: I found that LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING is required in Android 6.0 but not in 9. On Android 9 adding LayoutTransition.CHANGING to the parent fixed the issue and was enough, whereas on Android 6.0 the animation still acted weirdly without adding this to the child. Great answer and important comment!

Answer (score 53):

Ok, after digesting the first answer, I make it simple here, for those who don't get proper animation result when using `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in **NESTED** layout:

1. Make sure you add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the **will-be-resized** `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`/`FrameLayout`/`CoordinatorLayout`).
2. Use `setVisibility()` to control the visibility of your **target** `View`.
3. **Listen carefully from here,** add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the **outer** `ViewGroup` of your **will-be-resized** `ViewGroup`, this **outer** `ViewGroup` must be the one who wraps all the position-changing `View` affected by the animation.
4. Add following code in your `Activity` before the `setVisibility()`, here the `rootLinearLayout` is the outer `ViewGroup` I mentioned above:

   ```
    LayoutTransition layoutTransition = rootLinearLayout.getLayoutTransition();
    layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
   ```

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

---

**Reminder: If you miss the 3rd step, you will get null pointer exception.**

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I appreciate your effort to Include a GIF. Thanks a lot. +1

Comment: you are incredible, thank you a lot <3

Comment: What if you fast-click on the View? Does the transition animation still work as expected without blinking?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In my case I had to add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to the nested `ViewGroup` as well as its parent as you suggested. But, different to you, I had to call `.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)` on the nested `ViewGroup` and not on its parent.

Comment: I would add that sometimes you will need to `enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)` to several containers if you have several wrap_content containers.

Answer (score 11):

As a Kotlin Extension

```
fun ViewGroup.forceLayoutChanges() {
    layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
}
```

Usage

```
someContainer.forceLayoutChanges()
```

---

Notes:

In my experience, this happens when the container is a deep nested layout. For some reason `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` just doesn't work, but using this function will force it to work.

Comment: Let me be the 4th one to upvote your answer. Works more than a charm!! :)

Comment: @MakariKevin  Happy to help!

Comment: I found that `layoutTransition` can be null. So I added `if (layoutTransition == null) layoutTransition = LayoutTransition()` to the Kotlin Extension function to prevent unexpected NPE.

Answer (score 7):

We had added the android:animateLayoutChanges attribute to our LinearLayout but the change didn’t trigger an animation. To fix that, use this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.llRoot)).getLayoutTransition()
      .enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
}
```

[More details](https://proandroiddev.com/the-little-secret-of-android-animatelayoutchanges-e4caab2fddec).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a delayed transition on the parent also works for animating. At least for me the following code gives a proper expand/collapse animation.

```
expandTrigger.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentLayout);
        expanded = !expanded;

        child1.setVisibility(expanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
});
```

For deeply nested layouts you sometimes might need to use a parent higher up in the hierarchy in the call to the `TransitionManager`.

Comment: This is actually the only thing I could get to work to resize a PopUpWindow (via it's update method)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue:

I was using a animatelayoutchanges in one of my activity with a recycler view, I also added some custom layout transition because I wanted to increase speed of the animation while an item disappears in the list. It was working fine when it was not in a nested layout.

I had used the same adapter for another recyclerview which was in a nested layout. It was not working and I tried all the above solutions, None worked for me.

The real reason was, I forgot to set

```
mTicketsListAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```

in the nested layout activity. And after setting setHasStableIds to true, the animations was working perfectly in the nested layout.