# Show/Hide top bar like chrome, but with some static content and a listview

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, onscrolllistener

First let me give a short introduction and then show you what end goal looks:

So far I've added a scrolllistener to my listactivity, so that I can detect scrolling, though it does not give me any animation on `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`. So when i change the margin's of the view programmatically, it just does these changes instantly, and not that well, any help is most welcomed.

[image: End goal picture]

As you can see in my **xml**, i place the item I'm going to hide slowly first so other will be above it on the Z-axis.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:lector="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/background_greyish">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/disappearingHeaderLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/solid_white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="PRODUKTER"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_red"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/priceChooserButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/retailprice"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<dk.myapp.mobile.views.PageHeaderView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></dk.myapp.mobile.views.PageHeaderView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandingListContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/paginationBarContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="11">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sortAmountLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="1354"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sortLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:text="Produkter"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_red"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filterBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_red"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/retailprice"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:prompt="@string/sort" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@color/divider_color"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
 @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int marginRemoved = firstVisibleItem * 30;
        if (marginRemoved > 110) {
            marginRemoved = 110;
        }
        if (previousMarginRemoved != marginRemoved) {
            previousMarginRemoved = marginRemoved;

            LinearLayout disappearingHeaderContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.disappearingHeaderLabel);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) disappearingHeaderContainer.getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout expandingListViewContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandingListContainer);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams expandingListViewContainerParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) expandingListViewContainer.getLayoutParams();

            if (disappearingHeaderStartMargin == -1 && expandingHeaderStartMargin == -1) {
                disappearingHeaderStartMargin = disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams.topMargin;
                expandingHeaderStartMargin = expandingListViewContainerParams.topMargin;
            }

            float disappearingHeaderTopMarginFloat = disappearingHeaderStartMargin - (marginRemoved * pixelDensity);
            int disappearingHeaderTopMargin = Math.round(disappearingHeaderTopMarginFloat);

            if (marginRemoved > 50) {
                marginRemoved = 50;
            }

            float expandingContainerTopMarginFloat = expandingHeaderStartMargin - (marginRemoved * pixelDensity);
            int expandingContainerTopMargin = Math.round(expandingContainerTopMarginFloat);

            disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams.setMargins(disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams.leftMargin,
                    disappearingHeaderTopMargin,
                    disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams.rightMargin,
                    disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams.bottomMargin);

            expandingListViewContainerParams.setMargins(expandingListViewContainerParams.leftMargin,
                    expandingContainerTopMargin,
                    expandingListViewContainerParams.rightMargin,
                    expandingListViewContainerParams.bottomMargin);

            if ((lastChangeDate < System.currentTimeMillis()-100)) {
                lastChangeDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
                disappearingHeaderContainer.setLayoutParams(disappearingHeaderContainerLayoutParams);
                expandingListViewContainer.setLayoutParams(expandingListViewContainerParams);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's your minimum support level?

Comment: SDK version 14 (everything from 4 and up)

Comment: animateLayoutTransitions was introduced in 11, so this isn't going to work right in 4 - 10 anyway.  You can try suggested here and add the `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` which seems to be disabled by default for some reason.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103888/animatelayoutchanges-does-not-work-well-with-nested-layout

Comment: Also negative margins can crash on some devices.  The way I think they do it is by overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` and shifting the toolbar by View properties (Chrome minimum is 14).

Comment: Argh sorry @DeeV I meant 4.0.0 and up

Comment: I was working on a widget that actually does this then I ended up stumbling across this.  Maybe it'll help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559275/hiding-the-actionbar-on-recyclerview-listview-onscroll