# Animate Layout Changes broken in Nested Layout with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the following layout in my activity:

`CoordinatorLayout
┣━ AppBarLayout
┃  ┗━ CollapsibleToolbarLayout
┃     ┣━ TextView (parallax)
┃     ┣━ TextView (pin)
┃     ┗━ Toolbar
┗━ NestedScrollView
   ┗━ LinearLayout
      ┣━ TextView 1
      ┣━ LinearLayout 1
      ┃  ┗━ 1 to n Views (dynamically added/removed)
      ...
      ┣━ TextView n
      ┗━ LinearLayout n
         ┗━ 1 to n Views (dynamically added/removed)`

When I set the animateLayoutChanges in the Layouts to true, then whenever a Layout change happens inside of the NestedScrollView the resulting layout overlaps with the contents of the AppBarLayout.

I tried the suggestions in this [stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103888/animatelayoutchanges-does-not-work-well-with-nested-layout#comment45862595_22573099), But it didn't help.

Did anyone had a similar/the same problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 8):

Try calling setAnimateParentHierarchy(false) on the animated layouts.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html#setAnimateParentHierarchy(boolean)

Comment: Note that you should call this method using animated layout layoutTransition. For example: layout.getLayoutTransition().setAnimateParentHierarchy(false)