# View jumps and blinks instantly, though animateLayoutChanges="true"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I am making my **TabLayout** animated by using **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"** in **AppBarLayout**. But when I set **TabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)**, container for my fragment goes up to **ActionBar** instantly for a few milliseconds. And then it returns to the end of **TabLayout** and goes up with it to the **ActionBar**. I explained this on following gif.

[image: Following gif]

The buttons **Theory** and **Practice** are behind the **TabLayout** for some reason but when hiding TabLayout animation starts FrameContainer that holds my view sticks to the bottom of TabLayout.

I have recorded a video that demostrates this behavior. Dropbox video player skip some frames and animation seems nice. Thats why, to notice the bug, you can load video on computer and watch 5 and 11 second in high quality. [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6q0ziatinjslzhb/ScreenRecord_2016-03-23-17-59-56.mp4?dl=0)

***My LayoutXML:***

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!--
        This FrameLayout holds my fragments.
    -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/outer_background">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_load_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_full"
        layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In addition I am using **23.2.1 support libraries**.

**How can I fix this blinks and jumps?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your view with

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior
```

so that would be your DrawerLayout. Then enable Transition Type `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` on it like so:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id. drawer_layout);
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = layout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22573099/1363742

Answer (score 1):

I wasted all day to investigate this problem.
And I have found one possible solution for this problem.
Now i change visibility by this code

```
mTabLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (newMode) {
                case MODE_CONTENTS:
                    mTabLayout.setVisibility(mContents.isTheoryAvailable() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    break;
                default:
                    findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }, 200);
```

It works well and views are not blinking now. But on old androids the bug is still presents.