# Android adding simple animations while setvisibility(view.Gone)

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have designed a simple layout.I have finished the design without animation, but now I want to add animations when textview click event and I don't know how to use it.
Did my xml design looks good or not?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="16" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00DDA0"
    android:layout_weight="3" >
</LinearLayout>
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp" 
        android:text="Child Information" 
        android:background="#0390BE"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/layout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="8.5"
     android:background="#BBBBBB"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
         android:text="TextView" />
 </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:text="Parent Information" 
        android:background="#0390BE"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"/>
  <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:layout_weight="8.5" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
         android:text="TextView" />
      </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:text="Siblings" 
        android:background="#0390BE"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"/>
   <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:layout_weight="8.5" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
         android:text="TextView" />
      </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:text="Teacher Information" 
        android:background="#0390BE"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"/>
    <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/layout4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:layout_weight="8.5" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView4"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
         android:text="TextView" />
      </LinearLayout>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:text="Grade Information" 
        android:background="#0390BE"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"/>
     <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/layout5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:layout_weight="8.5" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
         android:text="TextView" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Information6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:text="Health Information" 
        android:background="#0390BE"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"/>
      <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/layout6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    android:layout_weight="8.5" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView5"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"        
         android:text="TextView" 
         android:layout_weight="8.5" />
      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**My java**

```
public class Certify_Info extends Activity {

    private static TextView tv2,tv3,tv5,tv6,tv4,tv1;
    private static LinearLayout l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_certify__info);

        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information1);
        tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information2);
        tv3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information3);
        tv4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information4);
        tv5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information5);
        tv6=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Information6); 

        l1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        l2=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
        l3=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        l4=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout4);
        l5=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout5);
        l6=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout6); 

        l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        l5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        l6.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        tv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        tv4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }
        });
        tv5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }
        });
        tv6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l4.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                l5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                l6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 887, accepted):

You can do two things to add animations, first you can let android animate layout changes for you. That way every time you change something in the layout like changing view visibility or view positions android will automatically create fade/transition animations. To use that set

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

on the root node in your layout.

Your second option would be to manually add animations. For this I suggest you use the new animation API introduced in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb). I can give you a few examples:

This fades out a `View`:

```
view.animate().alpha(0.0f);
```

This fades it back in:

```
view.animate().alpha(1.0f);
```

This moves a `View` down by its height:

```
view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
```

This returns the `View` to its starting position after it has been moved somewhere else:

```
view.animate().translationY(0);
```

You can also use `setDuration()` to set the duration of the animation. For example this fades out a `View` over a period of 2 seconds:

```
view.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(2000);
```

And you can combine as many animations as you like, for example this fades out a `View` and moves it down at the same time over a period of 0.3 seconds:

```
view.animate()
        .translationY(view.getHeight())
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(300);
```

And you can also assign a listener to the animation and react to all kinds of events. Like when the animation starts, when it ends or repeats etc. By using the abstract class `AnimatorListenerAdapter` you don't have to implement all callbacks of `AnimatorListener` at once but only those you need. This makes the code more readable. For example the following code fades out a `View` moves it down by its height over a period of 0.3 seconds (300 milliseconds) and when the animation is done its visibility is set to `View.GONE`.

```
view.animate()
        .translationY(view.getHeight())
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(300)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Natix I wouldn't call that super call redundant. Don't make superficial edits of there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Is good but the inverse not works correctly why ? view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); WITH alpha(1.0f), appear with 100 padding top ...

Comment: Must clear animation before set visibility >> `view.clearAnimation();` `view.setVisibility(View.GONE);` otherwise layout will remain invisible and not gone.

Comment: @Eftekhari That just happens because you use the old Animation framework instead of the newer animators.

Comment: @XaverKapeller ok. Thanks And any difference in performance with newer one?

Comment: @Eftekhari Is performing animation such a complicated and intensive task that there even are performance considerations? I think not... Animators, are a much better, much simpler, more versatile API. They have been around for ages now, I cannot understand why you still use view animations.

Comment: `Is performing animation such a complicated and intensive task that there even are performance considerations?` I think they are at least with my little experience when tried to animate ListView full of inner items(inner layouts as you would probably know).
CM cleaner and all the gallery apps that have animation inside them still have problems with lags and stuff like that.
`I cannot understand why you still use view animations` if performance is not matter at all so why should I use new library as I never felt a need?

Comment: @Eftekhari They are not at all resource intensive. And if you have an up to date Android version, but still experience lag than you probably have an older phone with low memory or a bad graphics chip. And I am not talking about a new library. Animators are native. They are part of the Android Framework. They have been released 5 years ago and today 97.9% of all devices support them. There is no reason not to use Animators or at least `ViewCompat.animate()` which is part of the support library and uses Animators on newer versions and View Animations on Android 3.0 and below.

Comment: But when 97.9% of all devices are Android 4.0 and up there isn't much of a usecase left for `ViewCompat.animate()`.

Comment: The key is to add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the root node and not in the UI element you want to toggle visibility and see being animated

Answer (score 191):

The easiest way to animate `Visibility` changes is use `Transition API` which available in support (androidx) package. Just call `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition` method then change visibility of the view. There are several default transitions like `Fade`, `Slide`.

```
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;
import androidx.transition.Transition;
import androidx.transition.Fade;

private void toggle() {
    Transition transition = new Fade();
    transition.setDuration(600);
    transition.addTarget(R.id.image);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
    image.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

Where `parent` is parent `ViewGroup` of animated view. Result:

[image]

Here is result with `Slide` transition:

```
import androidx.transition.Slide;

Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

[image]

It is easy to write custom transition if you need something different. Here is example with `CircularRevealTransition` which I wrote in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54532839/1372866). It shows and hide view with CircularReveal animation.

```
Transition transition = new CircularRevealTransition();
```

[image]

`android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` option does same thing, it just uses [AutoTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/AutoTransition?hl=en) as transition.

Comment: @TouhidulIslam no. This classes available in androidx package. Everything is backward compatible

Comment: What about expanding/collapsing a view group?

Comment: Can you do multiple `beginDelayedTransition`s?

Answer (score 56):

Try adding this line to the xml parent layout

```
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Your layout will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="16">

    .......other code here

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this worked for me. My setup uses a constraint layout as root view. When the view is set to View.VISIBLE the animation is shown

Comment: very simple and elegant solution

Comment: This was just awesome. I needed a transition for a 3 state toggle switch and this worked like a charm. Thank you so very much !!!

Answer (score 31):

Please check [this](http://colinyeoh.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/simple-android-animation-on-view-gonevisible/) link. Which will allow animations like L2R, R2L, T2B, B2T animations.

This code shows animation from left to right

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,view.getWidth(),0,0);
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

if you want to do it from R2L then use

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,-view.getWidth(),0,0);
```

for top to bottom as

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,view.getHeight());
```

and vice a versa..

Comment: This displaces the view from its original position.

Answer (score 30):

Base on @ashakirov answer, here is my extension to show/hide view with fade animation

```
fun View.fadeVisibility(visibility: Int, duration: Long = 400) {
    val transition: Transition = Fade()
    transition.duration = duration
    transition.addTarget(this)
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(this.parent as ViewGroup, transition)
    this.visibility = visibility
}
```

Example using

```
view.fadeVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
view.fadeVisibility(View.GONE, 2000)
```

Comment: this is the best solution, it's simple and works as well. thank you.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to show/hide a menu this way:

MenuView.java (extends FrameLayout)

```
private final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;

public void showMenu()
{
    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
            .setListener(null);
}

private void hideMenu()
{
    animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
}
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view#CrossfadeAnimate)

Answer (score 15):

Based on the answer of @Xaver Kapeller I figured out a way to create scroll animation when new views appear on the screen (and also animation to hide them).

It goes from this state:

- Button
- Last Button

to

- Button
- Button 1
- Button 2
- Button 3
- Button 4
- Last Button

and viceversa.

So, when the user clicks on the first button, the elements "Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3" and "Button 4" will appear using fade animation and the element "Last Button" will move down till end. The height of the layout will change as well, allowing using scroll view properly.

This is the code to show elements with animation:

```
private void showElements() {
    // Precondition
    if (areElementsVisible()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "The view is already visible. Nothing to do here");
        return;
    }

    // Animate the hidden linear layout as visible and set
    // the alpha as 0.0. Otherwise the animation won't be shown
    mHiddenLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mHiddenLinearLayout.setAlpha(0.0f);
    mHiddenLinearLayout
            .animate()
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_TRANSITION_TIME)
            .alpha(1.0f)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    updateShowElementsButton();
                    mHiddenLinearLayout.animate().setListener(null);
                }
            })
    ;

    mLastButton
            .animate()
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_TRANSITION_TIME)
            .translationY(mHiddenLinearLayoutHeight);

    // Update the high of all the elements relativeLayout
    LayoutParams layoutParams = mAllElementsRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams();

    // TODO: Add vertical margins
    layoutParams.height = mLastButton.getHeight() + mHiddenLinearLayoutHeight;
}
```

and this is the code to hide elements of the animation:

```
private void hideElements() {
    // Precondition
    if (!areElementsVisible()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "The view is already non-visible. Nothing to do here");
        return;
    }

    // Animate the hidden linear layout as visible and set
    mHiddenLinearLayout
            .animate()
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_TRANSITION_TIME)
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Animation ended. Set the view as gone");
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    mHiddenLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // Hack: Remove the listener. So it won't be executed when
                    // any other animation on this view is executed
                    mHiddenLinearLayout.animate().setListener(null);
                    updateShowElementsButton();
                }
            })
    ;

    mLastButton
            .animate()
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_TRANSITION_TIME)
            .translationY(0);

    // Update the high of all the elements relativeLayout
    LayoutParams layoutParams = mAllElementsRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams();

    // TODO: Add vertical margins
    layoutParams.height = mLastButton.getHeight();
}
```

Note there is a simple hack on the method to hide the animation. On the animation listener mHiddenLinearLayout, I had to remove the listener itself by using:

```
mHiddenLinearLayout.animate().setListener(null);
```

This is because once an animation listener is attached to an view, the next time when any animation is executed in this view, the listener will be executed as well. This might be a bug in the animation listener.

The source code of the project is on GitHub:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/ViewsAnimated

Happy coding!

**Update**: For any listener attached to the views, it should be removed after the animation ends. This is done by using

```
view.animate().setListener(null);
```

Comment: This one is the best answer

Comment: The `view.animate().setListener(null);` statement saved my day. This definitely seems to be a bug.

Comment: @MichalVician Glad it did!

Answer (score 8):

My solution extension

```
fun View.slideVisibility(visibility: Boolean, durationTime: Long = 300) {
    val transition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
    transition.apply {
        duration = durationTime
        addTarget(this@slideVisibility)
    }
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(this.parent as ViewGroup, transition)
    this.isVisible = visibility
    }
```

Use:

```
textView.slideVisibility(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the below code to make visible the view in Circuler reveal, if you send true, it'll get Invisible/Gone. If you send false, it'll get visible. anyView is the view you're going to visible/hide, it could be any view (Layouts, Buttons etc)

```
 private fun toggle(flag: Boolean, anyView: View) {
    if (flag) {
        val cx = anyView.width / 2
        val cy = anyView.height / 2
        val initialRadius = Math.hypot(cx.toDouble(), cy.toDouble()).toFloat()
        val anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(anyView, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0f)
        anim.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                anyView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        })
        anim.start()
    } else {
        val cx = anyView.width / 2
        val cy = anyView.height / 2
        val finalRadius = Math.hypot(cx.toDouble(), cy.toDouble()).toFloat()
        val anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(anyView, cx, cy, 0f, finalRadius)
        anyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        anim.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i reduce animation speed?

Comment: That can be controlled by library level by now. Up vote if you find it helpful

Answer (score 1):

Success with: boolean show = false;

```
private void toggle() {

show = !show;

Transition transition = new Fade();
transition.setDuration(600);
transition.addTarget(R.id.image);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
image.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

a different version

```
fun View.fadeIn(
        offset: Long = 0L,
        duration: Long = 200L,
        onStart: (() -> Unit)? = null,
        onFinish: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    if (!isAttachedToWindow) {
        onStart?.invoke()
        visible()
        onFinish?.invoke()
        return
    }
    val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in)
    anim.startOffset = offset
    anim.duration = duration
    anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) = onFinish?.invoke() ?: Unit
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            visible()
            onStart?.invoke()
        }
    })
    startAnimation(anim)
}

fun View.fadeOut(
        offset: Long = 0L,
        duration: Long = 200L,
        onStart: (() -> Unit)? = null,
        onFinish: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    if (!isAttachedToWindow) {
        onStart?.invoke()
        invisible()
        onFinish?.invoke()
        return
    }
    val anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out)
    anim.startOffset = offset
    anim.duration = duration
    anim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            invisible()
            onFinish?.invoke()
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            onStart?.invoke()
        }
    })
    startAnimation(anim)
}
```