# How to animate floating action button using android activity transition?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am planning to implement something like this in one of my project but the concept for the following is unclear to me, there's no such tutorial available either, moreover you don't get to see this very often. Here is how it looks like [Click here to go to source](http://a3.files.theultralinx.com/image/upload/MTI5MDI2MDM0MzQ2NTUzMzE0.gif)

[image]

> From all the references what i have understood is they have used two types of transition here one to move the button upto some extant and another to explode the button. So i did some digging and came across with these two library in `github` i think with these two we can achieve the following animation here are the links

[Material Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) (to move the button) and
[Circular reveal](https://github.com/ferdy182/Android-CircularRevealFragment) (to make the button looks like being exploded)

**If you find any better answer to the following please post here please**

Comment: Hope someone know how to do, because google examples are full of this type of transitions, but no one is explainend by code....

Comment: Can you please post the link to the examples that you have came across with?

Comment: Checkout this link this may help you https://github.com/saulmm/Curved-Fab-Reveal-Example **EDIT** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170786/how-to-fill-a-view-with-another-with-material-design-animation/30318641#30318641

Comment: I was taking a look to the Google Design specs (how has to be MatDesign) and his videos/gifs on how an animation has to be etc.. are really pretty transitions. Starting from Here http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/material-properties.html#material-properties-transforming-material you will find this specs and videos.

Comment: thanks a lot i have checked the specs but they just talk about it but never find any concept or  a piece of tuto there

Comment: I have found some vids on youtube, from "DevBytes Channel". Ussually the videos of  `Chet Haase` talks about transitions. I post you here one vid, but there's a lot.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA

Answer (score 15):

Question is old, however it is still interesting. That's how I implemented this:

[image]

First of all you need to create two `ViewGroups` which in transition api are called "scenes". First scene contains views before transition, second one contain views after transition. Then you should just replace first scene with second one and provide `Transition` which describes how views from first scene goes to second scene, also how views in first scene disappear and how views in second scene appear.

[image]

In this example there is difficulty with fab button, because it is the only view which is animated out of white area of "scene root" screen. Thats why scenes are fullscreen with  margin top which equals to height of blue "monday" header.

All transitions here are default except of yellow background transition. Yellow 
 background view appears in second scene with circular reveal animation. And it dissapear with circular reveal collapse animation. There is no default animation like this, thats why I wrote custom one:

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.support.transition.TransitionValues;
import android.support.transition.Visibility;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewAnimationUtils;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CircularRevealTransition extends Visibility {

@Override
public Animator onAppear(ViewGroup sceneRoot, View view, TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {
    int startRadius = 0;
    int endRadius = (int) Math.hypot(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2, startRadius, endRadius);
    //make view invisible until animation actually starts
    view.setAlpha(0);
    reveal.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            view.setAlpha(1);
        }
    });
    return reveal;
}

@Override
public Animator onDisappear(ViewGroup sceneRoot, View view, TransitionValues startValues, TransitionValues endValues) {
    int endRadius = 0;
    int startRadius = (int) Math.hypot(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, view.getWidth() / 2, view.getHeight() / 2, startRadius, endRadius);
    return reveal;
}
}
```

Full code is here:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.transition.ArcMotion;
import android.support.transition.ChangeBounds;
import android.support.transition.Fade;
import android.support.transition.Scene;
import android.support.transition.Slide;
import android.support.transition.Transition;
import android.support.transition.TransitionListenerAdapter;
import android.support.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.support.transition.TransitionSet;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewGroup mSceneRoot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        mSceneRoot = findViewById(R.id.sceneRoot);
        //show scene1 without animation
        showScene1(false);
    }

    private void showScene1(boolean animated) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scene1, null);
        FloatingActionButton fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            showScene2();
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(mSceneRoot, root);
        Transition transition = animated ? getScene1Transition() : null;
        TransitionManager.go(scene, transition);
    }

    private void showScene2() {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scene2, null);
        View btnBack = root.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            showScene1(true);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(mSceneRoot, root);
        Transition transition = getScene2Transition();
        TransitionManager.go(scene, transition);
    }

    private Transition getScene2Transition() {
        TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();

        //fab changes position
        ChangeBounds changeTransform = new ChangeBounds();
        changeTransform.addListener(new TransitionListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(@NonNull Transition transition) {
                //hide fab button on the end of animation
                mSceneRoot.findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        changeTransform.addTarget(R.id.fab);
        changeTransform.setDuration(300);
        //fab arc path
        ArcMotion arcMotion = new ArcMotion();
        arcMotion.setMaximumAngle(45);
        arcMotion.setMinimumHorizontalAngle(90);
        arcMotion.setMinimumVerticalAngle(0);
        changeTransform.setPathMotion(arcMotion);
        set.addTransition(changeTransform);

        //bg circular reveal animation starts
        CircularRevealTransition crt = new CircularRevealTransition();
        crt.addTarget(R.id.yellowBG);
        crt.setStartDelay(200);
        crt.setDuration(600);
        set.addTransition(crt);

        //buttons appear
        Fade fade = new Fade();
        fade.addTarget(R.id.btnBegin);
        fade.addTarget(R.id.btnCancel);
        fade.addTarget(R.id.text);
        fade.setStartDelay(600);
        set.addTransition(fade);

        //left buttons column slide to left
        Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
        slide.addTarget(R.id.slideLeftContainer);
        set.addTransition(slide);
        //right buttons column slide to right
        Slide slide2 = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
        slide2.addTarget(R.id.slideRightContainer);
        set.addTransition(slide2);
        return set;
    }

    private Transition getScene1Transition() {
        TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();

        //buttons from scene2 fade out
        Fade fade = new Fade();
        fade.addTarget(R.id.btnBegin);
        fade.addTarget(R.id.btnCancel);
        fade.addTarget(R.id.text);
        set.addTransition(fade);

        //Circular Reveal collapse animation starts
        CircularRevealTransition crt = new CircularRevealTransition();
        crt.addTarget(R.id.yellowBG);
        crt.setDuration(600);
        set.addTransition(crt);

        //then fab button changes position
        ChangeBounds changeTransform = new ChangeBounds();
        changeTransform.addTarget(R.id.fab);
        changeTransform.setDuration(300);
        changeTransform.setStartDelay(500);
        //arc path
        ArcMotion arcMotion = new ArcMotion();
        arcMotion.setMaximumAngle(45);
        arcMotion.setMinimumHorizontalAngle(90);
        arcMotion.setMinimumVerticalAngle(0);
        changeTransform.setPathMotion(arcMotion);
        set.addTransition(changeTransform);

        //left buttons column slide in from left
        Slide slide = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
        slide.addTarget(R.id.slideLeftContainer);
        slide.setStartDelay(500);
        set.addTransition(slide);

        //right buttons column slide in from right
        Slide slide2 = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
        slide2.addTarget(R.id.slideRightContainer);
        slide2.setStartDelay(500);
        set.addTransition(slide2);
        return set;
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:titleTextColor="#fff" />

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/topContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height"
    android:background="#00BCD4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#9000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="MONDAY"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sceneRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`scene1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slideLeftContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header_height"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/button" />
    <include layout="@layout/button" />
    <include layout="@layout/button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slideRightContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header_height"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/button" />
    <include layout="@layout/button" />
    <include layout="@layout/button" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFEE4D"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

`scene2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/header_height">

<View
    android:id="@+id/yellowBG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFEE4D" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFEE4D"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBegin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="BEGIN"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/header_height"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="#FF5151"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="CANCEL"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

`button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="6:30"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

`values.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestTransition</string>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_height">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin_top">132dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for are **Meaningful Transitions**.

In pre-lollipop devices this can be achieved with `ActivityOptionsCompat` helper.

Some useful links that might help you:

- a [simple material design tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/) (with source code) which uses
  ActivityOptionsCompat for transitions.
- Transitions example on the [Android Developrs blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html) (scroll down a
  bit).
- *Defining Custom Animations* in the Android Developers training
  guide