# How to fill a view with another with Material Design Animation?

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I'm trying to go around different functionality integrated with **Android Material Design** but I can't to do this type of animation when a view fill another like that :

**Do you know how to do it or a library/project an example that does this?**

[image]

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables please change the question of my post without close it. I just want to know how to do it and I think it's it is interesting for many people.

Comment: It's a Circular Reveal. You can find the basics [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution to do that is `pathInterpolator` and the name of this effect is **Curved Motion**.

> Animations in material design rely on curves for time interpolation
>   and spatial movement patterns. With Android 5.0 (API level 21) and
>   above, you can define custom timing curves and curved motion patterns
>   for animations.

You can see how to implement it here :

http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#CurvedMotion

And sample on GitHub **[HERE](https://github.com/saulmm/Curved-Fab-Reveal-Example)** :

[image]

Comment: but how to do it below API 21 ?

Comment: Good question, I think it's impossible or it's very complicated and not very efficient.

Answer (score 46):

I tried to implement this below API 21

add gradle dependancy

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.0.6@aar'
    }
```

My activity xml  is

> **activity_reval_anim.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RevalAnimActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"

        android:src="@drawable/ala"/>


    <io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_top"
        android:background="@color/color_primary">
        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/ll_reveal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_accent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            ></LinearLayout>

    </io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_floating_btn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/expand_btn"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity java is

> **RevalAnimActivity.java**

```
public class RevalAnimActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reval_anim);

        final ImageButton mFloatingButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_floating_btn);
        mFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                animateButton(mFloatingButton);


            }


        });

    }

    private void animateButton(final ImageButton mFloatingButton) {

        mFloatingButton.animate().translationXBy(0.5f).translationY(150).translationXBy(-0.9f)
                .translationX(-150). setDuration(300).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                animateReavel((int) mFloatingButton.getX(), 150,mFloatingButton);
            }
        });

    }

    private void animateReavel(int cx, int cy, final ImageButton mFloatingButton) {


        final View myView = findViewById(R.id.ll_reveal);

        // get the final radius for the clipping circle
        float finalRadius = hypo(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

        SupportAnimator animator =
                ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
        animator.addListener(new SupportAnimator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart() {
                mFloatingButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat() {
            }
        });
        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.start();

    }

    static float hypo(int a, int b) {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
    }


}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. To be perfect, I think you can change the elevation of your floating button to give the impression that it merges with the view (exactly as in the example). Just one question, the CircularReveal effect comes from the angle as in the example or the middle?

Comment: from the angle its start animation and where button animation ends it starts reveal from there