# Animation from one point to respective position in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am making animation from 0,100 to respective position create `TextView` , more details pictorial view.

From top left to created textview when loading UI.

[image]
and, normal line indicate moving from top to textview position.

[image]

In Simple way, **top left to any position animation** .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already posted answer, This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170786/how-to-fill-a-view-with-another-with-material-design-animation/30318641#30318641

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
private void translateTextView(TextView textView, int targetX, int targetY) {
        AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();

        ObjectAnimator y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v,
                    "translationY",textView.getY(), targetY);

        ObjectAnimator x = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v,
                    "translationX", textView.getX(), targetX);

        animSetXY.playTogether(x, y);
        animSetXY.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator(1f));
        animSetXY.setDuration(300);
        animSetXY.start();
    }
```