# Transform a Floating action button into an activity in Android

Tags: java, android, material-design, floating-action-button, activity-transition

I have a floating action button that, when pressed, starts a new activity.

Is there a way to animate it like on Google's Material design guidelines? I'm talking about something like [this](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B8v7jImPsDi-RWVHZjYybnlDeUE/components-buttons-fab-transition_fullscreen_02.webm) (from [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions)).

Comment: That looks like a "circular reveal animation". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958834/circular-reveal-transition-for-new-activity

Comment: @Floern It isn't exactly a circular reveal animation, because it first expands to the left and then goes up like a normal activity animation

Comment: @ Floern 
refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846458/how-to-animate-floating-action-button-using-android-activity-transition

Comment: @Rohitashvjain I'm not trying to reveal a view or a fragment, I'm talking about a completely different activity

Comment: i added a libs project link into answer,check this.

Comment: You can use this one. https://github.com/marshallino16/Demo-FloatingView

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft Isn't this just a floating button anywhere on the screen like Facebook's Messenger?

Comment: yeah same as hike button in Facebook messanger

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @marti201 I have answered check this out.

Answer (score 1):

As i have created a file in anim folder

right_bottom_up.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/time_fade"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%">
</translate>
```

no_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
   ></translate>
```

slide_down_back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/time_fade"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"></translate>
```

In activity
start your activity after intent calling:

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_bottom_up, R.anim.no_animation);
```

in your second activity onBackPress() write this line

```
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.slide_down_back);
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine this with a circular reveal animation?

Comment: I did not worked much, but you can check this out: http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below lib project , its same as you share video in this question.

https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab

May be this definitely helps you.

Comment: Still not what I need, this expands a "material sheet" and I need to start a new activity