# Animating the parent view without animating the child view

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to do something like this:
https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host/mio-staging%2Fmio-design%2F1563837804615%2Fassets%2F1XlKhaQFU9aS84ACmF-EDjVKDgI4pPldv%2F02-overflowmenu.mp4

[image]

I would like to squeeze a "ViewGroup" as you can see in the video. In the meantime, I want to fade out the content in the ViewGroup at its original position. i.e. not pushing the content to the right.

Any idea how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://github.com/hujiaweibujidao/FabDialogMorph. You have to do something similar i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do such animations with `Transition API`. Declare two `ViewGroup`s: first one is horizontal with cut/copy buttons, second is vertical with search/share buttons. Then switch these `ViewGroup`s with `TransitionManager`. Then just provide `Transition` which describes how views on first and second `ViewGroup`s appears and disappers.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.transition.ChangeBounds;
import androidx.transition.Fade;
import androidx.transition.Scene;
import androidx.transition.Slide;
import androidx.transition.Transition;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;
import androidx.transition.TransitionSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewGroup mSceneRoot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
        mSceneRoot = findViewById(R.id.sceneRoot);

        showPopup1();
    }

    private void showPopup1() {
        ViewGroup popup1 = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_1, mSceneRoot, false);
        popup1.findViewById(R.id.btnGo).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            showPopup2();
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(mSceneRoot, popup1);
        TransitionManager.go(scene, getTransition(false));
    }

    private void showPopup2() {
        ViewGroup popup2 = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_2, mSceneRoot, false);
        popup2.findViewById(R.id.btnBack).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            showPopup1();
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(mSceneRoot, popup2);
        TransitionManager.go(scene, getTransition(true));
    }
}
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sceneRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="150dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"/>
```

popup_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/popup1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="bg"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="go"
        android:transitionName="btn_go"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

popup_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/popup2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:transitionName="bg"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="back"
        android:transitionName="btn_back"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Last thing here is `getTransition` method. You can just use [AutoTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/AutoTransition), it can handle easy layout changes.

```
private Transition getTransition(boolean open) {
      return new AutoTransition();
}
```

Result:

[image: with AutoTransition]

Also just for demostration I wrote more complex transition where button on first viewgroup appear/dissapear with `Slide` animation.

```
 private Transition getTransition(boolean open) {
        Slide btnGo = new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT);
        btnGo.addTarget("btn_go");

        ChangeBounds bgBounds = new ChangeBounds();
        bgBounds.addTarget("bg");

        Fade btnBack = new Fade();
        btnBack.addTarget("btn_back");

        TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
        set.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL);
        if (open) {
            set.addTransition(btnGo);
            set.addTransition(bgBounds);
            set.addTransition(btnBack);
        } else {
            set.addTransition(btnBack);
            set.addTransition(bgBounds);
            set.addTransition(btnGo);
        }
        return set;
    }
```

Result:

[image: custom transition]

Note that `transitionName` for background should be same in both layouts.
All transition classes here are from `androix` package so code is backward compatible. But if you need support pre Lollipop devices you should set `transitionName` via `ViewCompat.setTransitionName` method.

You can check [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54532839/1372866) with more difficult/custom transition.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have a follow-up question. So, in your example, the right and bottom bound remains unchanged, while we change the top and left bound. Is that the default? Is there a way to change it if we want? Thanks.

Comment: `ChangeBounds` transition changes view bounds from bounds which are in first viewgroup to bounds which are in second viewgroup. In this example I place bottom right corner of both viewgroups into same position. Check `activity_layout.xml`  `android:gravity="bottom|right"` param. Thats why it looks like right and botton bounds doesn't change.