# How to adjust recyclerview height?

Tags: android, android-layout

**I want the recyclerview to adjust it's height so that the items don't get hidden behind the pricebar ( see image )**

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMainContainer"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mridulahuja.groceryapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@null" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPricebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#454560"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        ...
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code I'm using to resize recyclerview:

```
ViewTreeObserver pricebarvto = layoutPricebar.getViewTreeObserver();
pricebarvto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            layoutPricebar.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            layoutPricebar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
        pricebarHeight = layoutPricebar.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
});


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = relativeLayoutContainerHeight - pricebarHeight;
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where `relativeLayoutContainerHeight` is the height of the root RelativeLayout

But the height isn't changing. It's changing when I hard-code a big value 
to `pricebarHeight` such as 160. And I've given pricebar the height of just 50dp.

Also I'm using this animation to display the pricebar:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromYDelta="180%"
    android:toYDelta="0%">
</translate>
```

[image]

Comment: Use linear layout as vertical orientation with recyclerview and price bar.

Comment: convert main `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. You not need to set height of  `RecyclerView`

Comment: yes, you got my point.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that and let you know

Comment: use  android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view" in your innner relative layout.

Comment: and one thing set `weightSum=1` in main `LineraLayout` and set layout_weight =1 in recyclerview with match_parent height and width of it.

Comment: You can add the price bar as a footer to RecyclerView.

Comment: if your pricebar height is 50dp make RecyclerView android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" this will solve your issue no need of java code for resizing the Recyclerview

Comment: why the downvote ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [**`RelativeLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) then you should use [**`android:layout_marginBottom`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_marginBottom)

> Specifies extra space on the bottom side of this view. This space is
>   outside this view's bounds. Margin values should be positive.

**XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        ................
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
```

If you want [**`LinearLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) Then follow [**`android:weightSum`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219437/3395198) Logic .

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

Comment: thanks, it's working fine. I've removed the code to resize recyclerview in java. But now, since the bottom pricebar is animated and takes a couple of millisecs to come up, it leaves a gap between the pricebar and the new height of the recyclerview. is there a way to animate the recyclerview height change ?

Comment: @mrid Ji, Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454839/android-adding-simple-animations-while-setvisibilityview-gone

Answer (score 2):

Use linear layout with vertical orientation instead of relative layout and give recycler view

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMainContainer"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mridulahuja.groceryapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPricebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#454560"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        ...
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_above = "@id/layoutPricebar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@null" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the layout pricebar with id : layoutPricebar below the recycler_view by using android:layout_below: "@+id/recycler_view"

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutPricebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#454560"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone">
```

Answer (score 0):

if your pricebar height is 50dp make RecyclerView android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" this will solve your issue no need of java code for resizing the Recyclerview