# How to slide a view from right to left?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to slide a view from right to left whose visibility is `GONE` on click of a button and reverse on click of another button. I have tried the below solution. But it requires the view to be `VISIBLE` and it will slide the `view` from one position to another. I want to have a sliding effect as the `navigation drawer` does but with a `view`. How can I achieve that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

// Load the animation like this
animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide);

// Start the animation like this
imageView.startAnimation(animSlide);
```

Comment: what is not working here?

Comment: I need to keep my view visibility to GONE initially and when the user clicks the button I need to show the slide effect while making the view visible. Something similar to expand and collapse but this time horizontal.

Comment: With respect to **translate** also add **alpha** property to your animation will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility changes should be animated via `Transition API` which is available in support (androix) package :

```
private void toggle() {
    View imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);

    Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.LEFT);
    transition.setDuration(600);
    transition.addTarget(R.id.imageView);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
    imageView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648103/1372866) with more info.