# Android textview blinking after changing its visibility using animation

Tags: android, view, android-animation, visibility

I have some views in the constraint layout. I used animation to reveal and hide the view. When the view is GONE, it blinks for a second and become visible and then gone.

```
     view.animate()
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setDuration(300)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454839/android-adding-simple-animations-while-setvisibilityview-gone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your posted code and it seems to work just fine, except when `animateLayoutChanges` is turned on for the parent of the view you are trying to animate. If you have that enabled in the layout xml, turn it off and try again.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the answer here as I ran into this same problem. Using animateLayoutChanges in combination with the animation onAnimationEnd toggling the View visibility results in two animations running. The code runs once to set alpha to zero and the view disappears a first time. Then when the view is set to GONE in the onAnimationEnd code, a second animation runs from the layout's animateLayoutChanges setting that resets the alpha to 1 and fades out the view for a second time.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of using `AnimatorListenerAdapter`, replace it with `withEndAction`:

```
        view.animate()
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setDuration(300)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```