# How do I Animate a view from View.GONE to View.VISIBLE in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-animation

This is the structure of my layout xml:

```
<RelativeView>

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <...>

    </ScrollView>

    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeView>
```

When I want the view to appear, I use `View.VISIBLE` in the java file. I do this because I do not want the View to overlap the ScrollView.

Now, I want to animate the the view from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE`, so that it looks good.
*I know that Animations can be done from Alpha 0 to 1.*
**But is it possible to Animate from `View.GONE` to `View.VISIBLE`?**

Comment: it is very much possible .. try adding `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in root layout . Or if you want to set some custom animation [Check this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android adding simple animations while setvisibility(view.Gone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454839/android-adding-simple-animations-while-setvisibilityview-gone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your xml file and if you want **fade out** use `view.animate().alpha(0.0f);` in your java class and if you want **fade in** use `view.animate().alpha(1.0f);` .