# Circular hide with increasing radius - animation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

I know how to use CircularReveal to reveal a view, so I'm looking for a way to do something like "CircularHide". In other words, I want to invisible a view by a circular animation (increasing radius) after making it visible. How can I do that?

I've written this to reveal:

```
private void startCircularReveal() {
        RelativeLayout changeableLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutChangeable);
        int centerX = (likeButton.getRight() + likeButton.getLeft()) / 2;
        int centerY = (likeButton.getBottom() + likeButton.getTop()) / 2;
        float endRadius = (float) Math.hypot(changeableLayout.getWidth(), changeableLayout.getHeight());

        changeableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animator revealAnimator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(changeableLayout,
                centerX, centerY, 0, endRadius);
        revealAnimator.setDuration(200).start();
}
```

Comment: use transition api for visibility change animations https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648103/1372866

Comment: Well, I haven't found any answers to this question so far and I decided to change the design. Therefore, I changed "Circular Hide" (a circle that becomes bigger and makes the other views transparent) with "visibility change animations" as @ashakirov said.

If you have any further tricks, please share with me.