# OnClick in Fragment - Only Firing Once

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app has a tabbed screen with three fragments, two of which are the same but with different data.

[Initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmkIG.png)

[With comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/butQg.png)

Clicking the comment down the bottom brings up the full list of comments and clicking the [x] closes the comments. This is done through animations and .setVisibility().

The problem is I can only do this once as clicking the comment after closing it does nothing.

Bringing up the comments is shown here - from debugging, the onClick fires if I don't mess with the visibilities so they must be causing a problem somewhere

```
comment_overview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            handleCommentOverviewClick(v);
       }
});
...

private void handleCommentOverviewClick(View v) {
        Log.d("OPEN", "open");
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        bottomUp.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                bottom_info_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // animation.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        comment_section.startAnimation(bottomUp);
        comment_section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Closing the comments is similar and shown below

```
private void handleCommentsClose(View v) {
        Log.d("CLOSE", "cls");
        Animation topDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        topDown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                comment_section.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });
        comment_section.startAnimation(topDown);
        bottom_info_section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I've tried following advice of making the fragment implement OnClickListener and handling each clickable in a switch but I got the same behaviour - it would work once but not again unless I navigated away and came back.

Would love any suggestions as I'm kinda stuck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe local variable bottomUp, topDown will be deleted when handleComment ends. Then onAnimationEnd won't called back and the view isn't gone. Atempt to declare it outside.

```
Animation topDown;
```

```
topDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
```

Comment: Maybe. I did have it declared in onCreateView but made it its own function when I was trying a few other things. Will try it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the way I was animating it was messing it up. Switching to the Transition animations used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648103/8833124) helped.

```
private void handleCommentOverviewClick(ViewGroup v) {
        Log.d("OPEN", "open");
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

        Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        transition.setDuration(200);
        transition.addTarget(comment_section);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(v, transition);
        comment_section.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```