# Drop-down animation

Tags: android, animation, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop-down animation. When the user taps on a specified button `@+id/btnToHideView`, I would like a view `@+id/relativeLayoutControls` to drop down/slide up (`VISIBLE` / `GONE`).

Here is how the layout file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToHideView"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hide_btn"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutControls"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        //I have buttons in this layoout

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is what I have tried:

I created 2 animation files in `res/anim`

**slide_down.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Then I tried handling this by doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    controlsHide = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutControls);

    final Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.slide_down);

    final Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.slide_up);

    btnToHideView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnToHideView);

    btnToHideView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //I just did slide_up to test if its working
            controlsHide.startAnimation(slide_up);

        }
    });
```

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23926196/8199772), but when I tap on the button nothing happens. In logcat, it only prints `ACTION_DOWN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

**SlideUp:**

```
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_up);
view.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

slide_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

or

```
view.animate().translationY(0);
```

**Dropdown:**

```
view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
```

Comment: Replace `view` with your relative layout or button or any view that you want to animate. And replace `activity` with your context.

Comment: Turns out my logic was wrong, but you help me notice that, thank you.

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Here is my source code implementation ([refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925907/slidedown-and-slideup-layout-with-animation)), You can use them

```
// Initially hide/show the content view.
redLayout = mView.findViewById(R.id.history_operation);
//Load animation
slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_down);
slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);
```

- Create an animation xml for slide down and up. You can feel free to set the duration for the animation if you like. Here I set 500 milli:

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

and

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

- Implementing the animation in the source code:

  ```
    slide_up.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //When the animation was finished, set gone to the view
            redLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    slide_down.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            //When the animation start, set visible to the view
            redLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
  ```

Finally, calling the toggle function to start the defined animations

```
private void toggle1() {
    // Start animation
    if(isFadeOut){
        redLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);
    }else {
        redLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);
    }
    isFadeOut = !isFadeOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I don't like to use dependencies to keep app light as much as possible. But [Animation library](https://github.com/gayanvoice/android-animations-kotlin) has fun various animations:

**Java:**

```
Import render animations
import render.animations.*;
Start animation
// Declare yourlayout
yourlayout AppleText = findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);

// Create Render Class
Render render = new Render(MainActivity.this);

// Set Animation
render.setAnimation(Attention.Wobble(AppleText));
render.start();
```

**Kotlin:**

```
Import render animations
import render.animations.*
Start animation
// Declare yourlayout
val yourlayout: View = findViewById(R.id.layout_tag)

// Create Render Class
 val render = Render(this)

// Set Animation
render.setAnimation(Bounce().InDown(yourlayout))
render.start()
```

**Bonuse().InUp(yourview)** and try **Bonuse().InDown(yourview)**
[image]

**Slide().InUp(yourview)** and try **Slide().InDown(yourlayout)**
[image]