# How to create a drop drown animation?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

In my application i should create drop down animation.
For example, drop down fruits from top of screen into basket. such as below gif image : 
Animated image : https://media.giphy.com/media/gdN5P2svxsMhmRXIib/giphy.gif

But i want create this animation with smoothly effect!

I search from google and not found any animation such as this!

How can i create animation such as this?!

Comment: add some code snippets of what have you done so far

Comment: @TouhidulIslam, i post animation image! can you see this and help me? please

Comment: just posting a gif doesn't make it a proper question. take a look at this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can go to this topic and learn how implement what you want.

[HELP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232111/drop-down-animation)

Have good Coding ;)