# Slide-down/up menu

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hello i'm fairly new to Android development & I wanted to know how to make a slide-up/down menu by pressing on that black bar like the one in this picture.

Thank you

[slide hidden menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIzvX.jpg)

Comment: This Question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925907/slidedown-and-slideup-layout-with-animation):

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: welcome, you can voteup my comment

Comment: Can't see where to do so... that's really odd 