# Android: Slide out Animation

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout which is within a RelativeLayout and aligned to the bottom of it. It's height is wrap_content. What I'm trying to do is when the user presses a button and the action that the button does is completed, I want this LinearLayout to slide out of the bottom of the screen. So when the animation is done the LinearLayout will no longer be in the View.

When the animation happens what I'm actually seeing is the LinearLayout kind of flashes for  a second and then nothing happens.

Here's my XML for the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/splash_layout_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_screen_barcastr"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >


 <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/splash_loginBox"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/message_editor_background_shadow"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And this is my Animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Here's where I call it:

```
Animation slideOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.drawable.splash_login_slide_out);
            slideOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
            //Now Set your animation
            loginContainer.startAnimation(slideOutAnimation);
```

Comment: why don't you set the LinearLayout's visibility to Gone or sth else at this happend : onAnimationEnd()?

Comment: Because I hadn't thought of that. Thanks, that works! I added loginContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE); in onAnimationEnd and also changed my duration of the animation from 200 to 1000.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show and hide a View with a slide up/down animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation)

Comment: glad to help you, so add the answer to make others use it

Comment: Thank you, Even I wanted this

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:

```
@Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
          loginContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
```

after animation ended, make the the layout invisible