# Show and hide view animation in android

Tags: android, animation

[image]

I want to create an animation like this in android.
The problem is if I use anim from resources, I need to set visible my view first… and when I do that, the view at the bottom of the animated views are not sliding down like this, rather they just appears down.

Please help.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation

Comment: if your root layout is a linear layout, you can set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in it and change the visibility for the layout you want to appear, to visible in code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expandablelistview for your purpose...You can get the sample in the below link https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout