# How to make AwCollectionViewSlidingDoors on Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-sliding

I want to make a menu in an Android application that use `AwCollectionViewSlidingDoors` [animation](https://github.com/awdigital/AWCollectionViewSlidingDoors) like in iOS. This [application](https://appetize.io/app/bjr7f19dt0u73v4981r0rjteer?device=iphone5s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=9.3) uses it. I didn't find any implementation of such thing.

Comment: We cannot just provide ready solution to you.

Comment: Is there at least a lib that can help

Answer (score 1):

There is no existing library which offers this type of animated menu for Android, yet. If you want to achieve this, you will have to code it yourself. However it is relatively straight-forward. You just need to utilize the existing Android Animation API and integrate the slide-up/down in a menu.

See [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766034/5012320) to a question detailing this sort of animation and start educating yourself on the Android Animation API via the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html).