# How to get a smooth animation effect using Animation class?

Tags: java, android, animation

I have the following class to slide up a FrameLayout. It basically reduces height of the views. It works very well but the only thing is that the animation doesn't satisfy me on smoothness. It gives 10 FPS.

SlideUpDownAnimation.java

```
package anim;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

public class SlideUpDownAnimation extends Animation {
private static final String TAG = "ANIMATION";
private View view;
private boolean isUp;
private int startHeight;
private int finalHeight;
private int difference;

public SlideUpDownAnimation(View view, boolean isUp, int finalHeight) {
    this.view = view;
    this.isUp = isUp;
    this.startHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    this.finalHeight = finalHeight;
    this.difference = this.finalHeight - view.getLayoutParams().height;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    int newHeight;

    // daha yüksek bir değerden azalarak ilerliyor demektir.
    if (!isUp) {
        newHeight = (int) (this.difference * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        view.getLayoutParams()
                .height = newHeight;
    } else {
        newHeight = (int) (this.startHeight - (this.difference * interpolatedTime));
        view.getLayoutParams()
                .height = newHeight;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Start height: " + this.startHeight + " New height: " + newHeight + " interpolated time: " + interpolatedTime);

    view.requestLayout();
}
}
```

I set duration to 1000 milliseconds. Here's my logcat:

```
06-28 17:48:21.876 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 800 interpolated time: 0.0
06-28 17:48:21.876 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 800 interpolated time: 0.0
06-28 17:48:22.006 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 777 interpolated time: 0.061846644
06-28 17:48:22.116 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 739 interpolated time: 0.16699407
06-28 17:48:22.236 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 679 interpolated time: 0.33210987
06-28 17:48:22.356 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 613 interpolated time: 0.51570535
06-28 17:48:22.476 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 547 interpolated time: 0.6971313
06-28 17:48:22.591 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 493 interpolated time: 0.8468266
06-28 17:48:22.716 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 453 interpolated time: 0.9569855
06-28 17:48:22.831 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 438 interpolated time: 0.99944496
06-28 17:48:22.961 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 438 interpolated time: 1.0
06-28 17:48:23.076 13403-13403/com.menulux.menu I/ANIMATION: Start height: 800 New height: 438 interpolated time: 1.0
```

Comment: You may want to do this animation in XML. What is the current behavior at the moment?

Comment: It seems like device is lagging. It does 10 moves in a second. I want to increase it to more pleasant value like 30. applyTransformation is being called 10 times

Comment: Let me know if the solutions below worked for you.

Comment: Translation only moved the position of the view which I don't want. @A.Petrizza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything to make Animation class feed `interpolatedTime` more often to get smooth results of my animation but nothing worked. So I found the solution on creating my own Thread to animate object. The below animation works well at 60 FPS.

```
public class AdjustMediaHeight extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private View ll_food_media;
    private int videoHeight;
    private final int startHeight;
    private final int difference;

    public AdjustMediaHeight(View view, int height) {
        this.ll_food_media = view;
        this.videoHeight = height;
        this.startHeight = ll_food_media.getMeasuredHeight();
        this.difference = ll_food_media.getMeasuredHeight() - videoHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        float i = 1;
        long lastMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (i < 60) {
            // closest frame rate compared to 33,33333333333
            // 33 comes from 30 / 1000
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastMilli < 16)
                continue;

            final int newHeight = (int) (startHeight - (difference / 60 * i));

            APP.mOrderActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ll_food_media.setLayoutParams(
                            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    800,
                                    newHeight
                            )
                    );

                    ll_food_media.requestLayout();
                }
            });

            Log.i("ANIMATION", "Frame #" + i + " completed. Height: " + newHeight);
            i++;
            lastMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

***WARNING: Don't mix this with other animations. Because its work handled by CPU so it can lag the entire device for 1 second.***

Answer (score 0):

You can slide a `View` down a distance with `view.animate().translationY(distance);`

Then slide it back to its original position with: `view.animate().translationY(0);`

You can also make some interesting combinations such as:

```
// Prepare the View for the animation
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setAlpha(0.0f);

// Start the animation
view.animate()
    .translationY(view.getHeight())
    .alpha(1.0f);
```

That will slide down by its height and then fade away.

You could fade that view back to its original position as well.

With `AnimatorListener` you can set the `view` to 'gone' after the animation has finished as well.

reference here : [Show hide view with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation)

If you want to go the XML route. This may also be a good option here:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

These deltas can be changed for a different effect/direction

Answer (score 0):

You can use android transition classes https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html.
They are smooth and you can also apply 4 types of transitions:

- Exit Transition
- Enter Transition
- Return Transition
- Re-enter Transition

They also give you independence to perform transition in java class or xml file.

Snippet of using them in java class

**ENTER TANSITION**

```
ACTIVITY A:
ActivityOptionsCompat compat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activityA.this,null);

            Intent i = new Intent(activityA.this,activityB.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                startActivity(i,compat.toBundle());
            }
            else
                startActivity(i);

ACTIVITY B:

Slide s = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        s = new Slide();
        s.setDuration(1000);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(s);
    }
```

For xml files, you'll have to create Transition resource file and inflate it in your java class.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks but my application should support back to API 14. This Transition class come into business at API 19.