# How do I add animation to BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-animation, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment which has two buttons in it and when I click on any button dismiss() method is called. Is there a way by which I can animate BottomSheetDialogFragment. I want it to show a slow sliding down animation with a duration of 1000ms.

Sample code

```
   signin.findViewById(R.id.signin_button_using).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callback.onClickSignInEmail();
            dismiss();
        }
    })
```

Comment: Pls. refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation

Comment: @pritesh onClickSignInEmail() takes us to a new fragment. If you understand correctly **BottomSheetDialogFragment** it uses dismiss() to end the bottomsheetdialog and the article you doesn't help

Answer (score 38):

In your fragment which is extended with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, try overriding this method like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    getDialog().getWindow()
    .getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
}
```

DialogAnimation can be defined in the styles like this

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

Further, slide_up and slide_down would be your implementation of required animation. You can find plenty of example for the same online.

Comment: I have added slide_up and down animation. But it seems like duration is not working. I've also added duration of 1500ms



**slide_down.xml**


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />`

Comment: link for sample slide animation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This animates the whole window, but the visible part – the bottom sheet dialog – is typically much smaller than the window (the remaining space is transparent), so there will be a delay where you're just sliding a transparent view over the background. Turn on Show layout bounds in developer settings to see this in action.

I think you should animate the *view* instead. Not sure how yet; working on it.

Comment: any help here. I am trying to animate BottomsheetDialogFragment while exit