# Animate ButtomSheetDialogFragment to slide down slowly on dismiss()

Tags: android

I have a ButtomSheetDialogFragment in my activity. When I click a button in the ButtomSheetDialog I want to programatically dismiss it in a way where it slides down in a slow fashion. At the moment when I call dismiss() on the dialog it just disappears without doing any animation.

How do I programatically add a sliding animation to the ButtomSheetDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly do not know how, after hours of search I did not find [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693846/how-do-i-add-animation-to-bottomsheetdialogfragment) sooner.

It describes exactly what I want to achieve.