# How to animate view to slide down and push down everything below it?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, android-view

So I have looked into how to animate fade and drop down/slide up animations of Views using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation), however it didn't quite work as expected. To begin with, here is the code I use for the animating:

```
public void toggleAdvancedVisibility(View text) { //text is a clickable textview thats acts as a toggle
    int dur = 1000;
    final View advView = findViewById(R.id.enc_advanced);
    if(advView.getVisibility() == View.GONE && animationDone) {
        advView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        advView.setAlpha(0.0f);

        //animate fade + drop down
        advView.animate()
                .setDuration(dur)
                .translationY(advView.getHeight())
                .alpha(1.0f)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        animationDone = true;
                    }
                });
        animationDone=false;
    }
    else if(advView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && animationDone) {
        //animate fade + slide up
        advView.animate()
                .setDuration(dur)
                .translationY(0)
                .alpha(0.0f)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        advView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        animationDone = true;
                    }
                });
        animationDone = false;
    }
}
```

As I said, while there was animation, it didn't act anywhere near as expected.

**Problem #1**
The view is almost pushed out of visibility. I believe that this is due to the line `.translationY(advView.getHeight())` as if I set the location of the view before the animation to `advView.setTranslationY(-advView.getHeight())` and then animate `.translationY(0)` it goes to where it is supposed to.

The obvious problem with this is that while the view is animating, the view "collides" with the view above it before it is done. So how do I properly get this to slide down/up without running into the view above it?

**Problem #2**
The animation doesn't exactly "push" the view down, which is what I expected. What I mean by this is that the view being animated also has a view below it. I expected the view below it to be pushed down with the animated view. While I haven't tried it yet, I assume this can be simulated by setting the same animation to the view below it, but is there another way of doing it?

I am very new to this animation stuff and manipulating Views like this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: use `android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar` as a base class or (if you need different behavior) see its sources to get to know how it is done

Comment: @pskink Do you have a specific link or source that I could use? I am reading the documentation and I believe I understand to a degree what I am supposed to do, but not certain. I also can't find any good examples of it being used.

Comment: ask uncle google  for `BaseTransientBottomBar.java`

Comment: @pskink I did, all I found was source code and information relating to `SnackBar`s, which I know nothing about. None of it helps me in figuring out how to implement it

Comment: so if you have the source of `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar` you have all of it - `Snackbar` extends `BaseTransientBottomBar`

Comment: @pskink I am still unsure how to apply this or what it does exactly. Especially in the xml layout file.

Comment: so do you want to change the behavior of `Snackbar` or just use it as it is?

Comment: @pskink I don't see how `Snackbar` is relevant. From my understanding `Snackbar` is just displaying text at the top of the screen for brief information, similar to `Toast`, which isn't what I am trying to do.

Comment: yes, `Snackbar` is doing `"drop down/slide up animations of Views"`, more preciously it is done by `BaseTransientBottomBar`

Comment: Ok, so I get `Snackbar` has similar behavior to what I want, but I still don't understand how to use `BaseTransientBottomBar`, as it doesn't even have a public constructor and I have no idea how I would add it to what I already have.

Comment: @pskink Ok, I get that, what I don't get is how I'm supposed to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a short example and I see it pushes down the rest of the view.
xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.teststuff.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:text="show"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!!!!"/>
```

and here is the .java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (tv1.isShown()){
                tv1.startAnimation(slideInAnimation(view));
                tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                tv1.startAnimation(slideOutAnimation(view));
                tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });


}

private TranslateAnimation slideOutAnimation(View view){
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-view.getHeight(),0);
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(false);
    return animate;
}
private TranslateAnimation slideInAnimation(View view){
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-view.getHeight());
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    return animate;
}
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Problem still persists. Maybe it's because I am trying to move an entire `LinearView`?

Comment: can you explain what is your exact problem now? it does't push your view down? does it come over it?

Comment: Still the same problem, the animated view goes over top of the view above it. Also doesn't move the view below it.

Comment: in what layout are your views that animate?

Comment: A `LinearLayout` that contains buttons, Edittexts, and TextViews.