# Hide android toolbar with slide up animation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-gesture

I have a ToolBar that I want to show or hide with an Animation that pushes the layout upwards or downwards whenever I change its visibility.

[image]
[image]

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766034/6559031