# Is there a way to make a listview appear with a slide animation when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, button, slide

I'm developing an m3u livestreaming app, and I want to show all of the channels in a listview. Now I don't know how to make a listview appear from the right as shown in the picture with a slide animation when a button is clicked and make it disappear (slide out animation) when I click the button again.

Can somebody help me out ?[picture of what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azPdq.png)

Edit: I tried this, but it didn't work unfortunately.

```
//slide in imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgbuttonisclicked = true;
                ValueAnimator widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 255);
                widthAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        int animatedValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        list.getLayoutParams().width = animatedValue;
                        list.requestLayout();
                    }
                });

   //slide out      if (imgbuttonisclicked){
                    widthAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(255, 0);
                    widthAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            int animatedValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            list.getLayoutParams().width = animatedValue;
                            list.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps play on the width property of the list. Set it to 0 at first then on the button click event animate it to a bigger width. You can learn more about property animation in this [article](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-property-animation-the-valueanimator-4ca173567cdb).

Edit: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766034/9932083) provides a better solution.

Comment: Thank you. I experimented with the code in the article and tried this (see my edit code), but it didn't work :(

Comment: Your code is missing a call to widthAnimator.start(). You could also add duration with setDuration().
I've added a link in my post to another stackoverflow topic that could provide a better solution.