# how to make view visible and gone with some animation?

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a relative layout, I need to show that view when network connectivity is not there and gone that view when connection came back, I need to do it like youtube. YT will show the popup in bottom with green color and after sometimes the view slide down. Thanks in advance I am new to this. I can't find any equivalent answer in StackOverflow

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/dashboard_xmpp_connection_status_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_xmpp_connection_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        style="@style/Connection_status"
        android:text="@string/msg_no_internet" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which kind of animation you required?

Comment: As same as in youtube, slide down and slide up @Ankita

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show and hide a View with a slide up/down animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation)

Comment: no @Md.Asaduzzaman

Answer (score 0):

```
    binding.filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (binding.filterExams.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(binding.filterExams.getRootView().getContext(),
                        R.anim.slide_up_filter);
                slide_down.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        binding.filterExams.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                binding.filterExams.startAnimation(slide_down);

            } else {
                binding.filterExams.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(binding.filterExams.getRootView().getContext(),
                        R.anim.slide_down);

                binding.filterExams.startAnimation(slide_down);

            }
        }
    });
```

you can add animation file in xml file for e.g

here i used slide down  and up animation

slide_up_filter.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
  </set>
```

slide_down.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<scale
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
 </set>
```

like this there are sevaral animation

```
fade_in.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
 <alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0">
 </alpha>
 </set>

 fade_out.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transition API which is available in **Support(androidx) package**.

To use this you have to call TransitionManager.geginDelayedTransition method and change the visibility of the view to visible and gone as per the requirement.

```
  private void slideView(boolean show) {
        Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        transition.setDuration(600);
        transition.addTarget(R.id.id_of_relative_layout);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(id_of_relative_layout, transition);
        if(show){
           relativeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
           relativeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
   }
```

Call slideView() function on the action from where you want to perform it.

For more deatil follow this - 
[Show and hide a View with a slide up/down animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation)

Comment: what's parent in beginDelayedTransition?

Comment: id of relative layout or you can say view which you want to animate/show-hide.

Answer (score 0):

so you can use LottieAnimationView

your app gradle file

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.7'//2.7.0
```

go this website sign and download free lottie json file

[please click](https://lottiefiles.com/#)

```
   step 1:put this download lottie json file to android studio assets folder
```

your layout file

```
  <FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/dashboard_xmpp_connection_status_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
         android:id="@+id/showAnimations"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_height="66dp"
         android:layout_width="56dp"
         android:visibility="gone"
         app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
         app:lottie_loop="false"
        app:lottie_fileName="animsix.json" <!--please put your download  json file -->
                />        


</FrameLayout>



 MainActivity


LottieAnimationView showLottie=findViewById(R.id.showAnimations);   

 if("network is available"){
    showLottie.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }else{
    showLottie.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use fade in animation for text view like this.

```
void fadeIn() {
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setAlpha(0);
    int duration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);
    textView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(duration);
}
```

`textView.animate()` returns `ViewPropertyAnimator` which contains various methods to customize animations.

[Visit this for more details](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reveal-or-hide-view)