# Android Studio Custom Spinner Layout

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I'm a beginner in Android programming. Currently I want to implement an app with the component like the one you may see in the picture below. Could you give me any hints how to make it? As I see it looks like a dropdown spinner. I know how to make a spinner but how to add additional views like buttons ("NEW" and "EDIT") and textviews ("2 notes" and "categories"). What to start with?

[image]

Comment: Just use LinearLayout and animate it accordingly to show/hide when the dropdown button is clicked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765938/show-and-hide-a-view-with-a-slide-up-down-animation

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to do as you said.