# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator android.widget.ImageView.animate()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm trying to make a simple animation with a image that iniatially it doesn't appear but after it appears rotating 180 degrees for certain a amount of seconds from the left of the screen.
So i made a script inside the onCreate method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView Bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);
        Bart.animate().translationXBy(-3000);
        Bart.animate().translationXBy(4000).rotation(180).setDuration(2000);


    }
```

But for some reason i'm getting an error saying that i'm trying to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference.What could be the issue?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set `setContentView()` in `onCreate`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)// add this with your layout Id
    ImageView bartImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);
    bartImageView.animate().translationXBy(-3000);
    bartImageView.animate().translationXBy(4000).rotation(180).setDuration(2000);


}
```

Also few suggestions take variables with camelCase starting with small letter . Add some identifier to the variable which indicates what it is, like `bartImageView`  or `bartIV` etc.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for answering my question.I trying to make the image disappear iniatially from the screen by doing `bartImageView.animate().translationXBy(-3000);` but it doesn't work.Do you know what it could be the problem?

Comment: You can hide image view by using `bartImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: I did that but i tried animating in the next line and it doesn't appear again

Comment: To make it visible use `bartImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: Is there a way to make it go off the screen but not disappear using translationXBy?And then go back again using translationXBy?This is what i was trying to do

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601913/6478047

Comment: Thanks Manohar.I find out that i wanted setX instead of translationXBy.