# Transition Manager - Sliding a view out is not working as wanted

Tags: android, android-transitions

[image]

I'm trying to slide this view in and out using Transition + Transition manager, however when hitting the hide button to make the view `GONE` it doesn't have the sliding animation. However, the show button does have the sliding in animation to make the view `VISIBLE` again.

```
    @OnClick(R.id.testBtn)
        public void onTestBtnClick(){
            //hide
            Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.START);
            transition.setDuration(600);

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mParentLayout, transition);
            mLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.testBtn2)
        public void onTestBtn2Click(){
            //show
            Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.START);
            transition.setDuration(600);

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mParentLayout, transition);
            mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

I've tried changing the gravity of `testBtn2` to `Gravity.END`, but that causes it to slide all the way starting from the right side of the screen.

Here's the layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_root_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Hide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testBtn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/testBtn"
        android:text="show"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_side_bar_corners"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whats wrong with your code. i have created a sample, just try the code below it working fine. make sure to add `android:visibility="gone"` for panel view in layout so that its hidden at first launch.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean isShowing = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_damm_activty);
    findViewById(R.id.testBtn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        showSlidingPanel(!isShowing);
    });
}

private void showSlidingPanel(boolean show) {
    ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_root_view);
    View layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    Transition transition = new Slide(Gravity.START);
    transition.setDuration(450);
    transition.addTarget(R.id.layout);
    transition.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parent, transition);
    layout.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    isShowing = show;
}
}
```

Comment: The slide in animation works, but how can I get it to slide out?

Comment: It is Sliding out also . i have added both cases in above method . Its working fine for Slide In and Slide out both .

Comment: Is this what you were expecting? https://streamable.com/0j3wvj this is what im getting

Comment: Nope . It's sliding out at my end . How come it's not working on your device .

Comment: Just to make things clear I am using Android x version of TransitionManager and other classes.

Comment: Very weird issue. The one in the video above is a emulator Pixel 2 API 29. I just tried it on my Nexus 5X API 27 and the slide out animation works. Im also using the AndroidX one.

Comment: Tested on my real device Pixel 4a API 30, doesn't work on it either. Also...I just tested my code above and it works on the Nexus 5X...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It looks like setting a view to GONE just immediately takes effect and kills transition manager animations now, and it didn't used to?

Answer (score 1):

The excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66549169/1866373) is very similar to this question.

I have noticed the constraint layout needs to be set up very specifically - if the view you are setting to GONE is constrained to it's sibling, those constraints seem to take precedence over any transition manager animation, i.e. setting a view to GONE just instantly kills it instead of smoothly animating, because the other view's constraints kick in immediately.

My solution was to use a guideline and have two views constrained to it, and set the GuidelineBegin for the transition manager. Just another option that may help:

```
        val rootView = binding.constraintLayout
        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(rootView)
        val transition = AutoTransition()
        transition.duration = 150L
        transition.excludeTarget(R.id.orders_recycler_view, true)

        constraintSet.setGuidelineBegin(binding.guideline.id, if (showingDetailView) 0.px else 64.px)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView as ViewGroup, transition)
        constraintSet.applyTo(rootView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create these animations

slide up

```
<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

slide down

```
<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

When you want to set the layout visible

```
binding.musicOptionsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); binding.musicOptionsLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down));
```

When you want to set the layout Gone

```
binding.musicOptionsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); binding.musicOptionsLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.slide_down));
```

set `android:visibility="gone"` on XML..

Hope this will fix your issues...

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin solution

1. Call the method wherever you want. Use FALSE to Slide out and TRUE
   to Slide in.
2. **targetView** = View you want to slide in / out
3. **rootLayout** = Main layout where the **targetView** is located
4. In this example, it will slide from RIGHT to LEFT. If you want LEFT
   to RIGHT, change Gravity.END to Gravity.START

   ```
    private fun shareSlideInOut(show: Boolean) {
        val slide = Slide(Gravity.END)
        slide.duration = 450
        slide.addTarget(targetView)
        slide.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout, slide)
        shareCodeLayout.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
   ```