# ConstraintLayout Slide Transition animation is displaying the view's full height before the animation ends

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions, constraintset

I have the following Activity and layout:

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet
import androidx.transition.Slide
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager
import com.tests.playground.R


class ConstraintLayoutTransitionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val rootView: ConstraintLayout by lazy { findViewById(R.id.root) }
    private val bottomBlueView: View by lazy { findViewById(R.id.bottomBlue) }
    private val switchButton: View by lazy { findViewById(R.id.switchButton) }
    private var isBottomBlueViewShowing = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_constraint_layout_transition)

        switchButton.setOnClickListener(::onSwitchButtonClicked)
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun onSwitchButtonClicked(view: View) {
        isBottomBlueViewShowing = !isBottomBlueViewShowing

        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(rootView)

        val transition = Slide()
        transition.duration = 1000L

        if (isBottomBlueViewShowing) {
            constraintSet.setVisibility(bottomBlueView.id, View.VISIBLE)
            transition.slideEdge = Gravity.BOTTOM
        } else {
            constraintSet.setVisibility(bottomBlueView.id, View.GONE)
            transition.slideEdge = Gravity.BOTTOM
        }

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, transition)
        constraintSet.applyTo(rootView)
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topRed"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomBlue"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Switch"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/topRed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/topRed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/topRed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topRed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomBlue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:background="#00F"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I try to show/hide the bottomBlue, here's what happens:

[image: Flick]

As you can see,

- when I hide the view the button goes straight down without animating (the bottomBlueView animation is ok`;
- when I show the view the button also goes straight up without animating. But what bugs me the most is that a white area is show before the animation starts and sticks there until the end.

Is there any way to solve theses animations problems?
I've already tried many ways (with `ConstraintSet` and `Animation`) but none of them work as expected.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `AutoTransition` for transition.

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, AutoTransition())
```

Result will be like this:

[image: AutoTransition]

`AutoTransition` uses [Fade](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/Fade) transition for visibility changes of blue area.
If you need blue area to slide you should provide custom transition. It should be `ChangeBounds` transition for red area and blue button and `Slide` transition for blue area:

```
private val topRed: View by lazy { findViewById(R.id.topRed) }
  
private fun onSwitchButtonClicked(view: View) {
        isBottomBlueViewShowing = !isBottomBlueViewShowing

        val transitionSet = TransitionSet()
        transitionSet.ordering = TransitionSet.ORDERING_TOGETHER

        //blue btn
        val blueBtnTransition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        blueBtnTransition.addTarget(bottomBlueView)

        //red area + switch btn
        val topRedTransition = ChangeBounds()
        topRedTransition.addTarget(topRed)
        topRedTransition.addTarget(switchButton)

        transitionSet.addTransition(blueBtnTransition)
        transitionSet.addTransition(topRedTransition)

        val blueBtnVisibility = if (isBottomBlueViewShowing) {
            View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            View.GONE
        }

        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(rootView)
        constraintSet.setVisibility(bottomBlueView.id, blueBtnVisibility)

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, transitionSet)
        constraintSet.applyTo(rootView)
    }
```

Here is result:

[image: custom_transition]

As you can see there is still white area between red and blue areas when it animates. You can solve it via adding delays to transitions:

```
    blueBtnTransition.startDelay = if (isBottomBlueViewShowing) 0 else 100
    topRedTransition.startDelay = if (isBottomBlueViewShowing) 100 else 0
```

Here is result. IMHO with delays it looks much better:

[image: with_delays]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your very detailed explanation. I've just tried it on an emulator and on a physical device but the result I get is just like the second gif. Do you remember if you did anything else? Thanks again ^^

Comment: You need to set `LinearInterpolator` to blue and red transitions, only after that their bordering edge will animate exactly, without visual white gaps. But problem here is that `Slide` transition uses `AccelerateInterpolator`/`DecelerateInterpolator` for hide/show animation and as I've see from sources you can't change that behaviour via `setInterpolator` method. The best solution here is to write custom `Slide` transition which will support `LinearInterpolator` or try to hide that gap with delays, different animation durations etc