# Animation for relative layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I am trying to set animation for a relative layout in one of my activity_main.xml layout. I want the relative layout to slide upward when visibility is set to visible, and slide downward when visibility is set to gone/invisible.
But I was only able to get the animation to slide upward and slide downward once. When I clicked the button again to have the layout slide upward again (and set to visible), the layout just popped out without animation; and as well as when I clicked the button again to have it slide downward (and set to gone/invisible), the layout also just disappears without animation.
I would really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Here is what I have tried:

```
Private RelativeLayout relLayoutInfo = findViewById(R.id.rel_Layout_Info);
Private Button btnSlideUp = findViewById(R.id.btn_Up);
Private Button brnSlideDown = findViewById(R.id.btn_Down);
private Animation extraInfoAnimationEnter = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.details_info_animation_enter);
Private extraInfoAnimationExit = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.details_info_animation_exit);

btnSlideUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                relLayoutInfo.setAnimation(extraInfoAnimationEnter);
                relLayoutInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
btnSlideDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                relLayoutInfo.setAnimation(extraInfoAnimationExit);
                relLayoutInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

This is the animation file for extraInfoAnimationEnter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="500">

    </translate>
</set>
```

This is the animation file for extraInfoAnimationExit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:duration="500">

    </translate>

</set>
```

Comment: Use transition api for visibility change animations. Check this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144349/1372866

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact solution but only a suggestion, there is a `MotionLayout` also available [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples)

And also playlist by official channel of AndroidDevs [here](https://youtu.be/M1jE3W3_NTQ)

MotionLayout is great for animations, but if this isn't what you want we can try to implement it in your `RelativeLayout` :)

Comment: MotionLayout works only in constraint layout 2.0.0 and up and It is a viable solution in this case.