# Android kotlin spinner

Tags: android, kotlin

there is a feature that I actually don't know it's name. when click on a button then screen drop down a menu of items, like spinner , like this photo . I'm a newbie so I'm grateful to your help. Thank you so much [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrgJd.jpg)

I tried to use spinner but actually it doesn't work

Comment: This is not spinner, this is expandable listview

Comment: @ManojPerumarath i am so grateful to your help, thank you so so much, you just save my day =)))

Comment: @Cam
See this (answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46644736/8644685). There is a GIF. Is this what you need?