# FragmentTransaction with CustomAnimation android 4+

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

I've notice that since android 4+ we cannot use the  animation anymore and only objectAnimator.

I'm trying to use slide-in animation according to Y scale. (should start from -100% > 0 and 0 > 100%)
Thing is that objectAnimator only gets float value.
Example for one of the animation:

```
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:propertyName="y"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:valueFrom="-1280"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:duration="500"/>
```

How can I set the **valueFrom & valueTo** to run ok on all screens? Or maybe there's another way to implement this animation.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Roman Nurik's answer here, he shows a full-screen scalable slide animation by creating a custom property:

[Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)