# Using ViewPager component

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am new to Android development. I am creating an application with `Fragments`.  Following is the Diagram.

[image]

`Home` screen is having the root access to all the other screens. `Sales` is a `ViewPager` and all the other screens after sales are part of it. User can slide and access.

But I do have a problem. I am planning to use one `FragmentActivity` for this application. It is the `Home`. Home screen is a collection of buttons, with images. If the user click on 'Sales' button then the `Home` screen flips just like `ViewPager` animation and access `Sales` screen;  if the user click on 'TimeManager' button then the `Home` screen flips just like `ViewPager` animation and access `TimeManager` screen and so on.

Following is the code of the `HomeScreen`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

    }
```

Now imagine I am in `Sales` screen. As I mentioned earlier, it has sequence of pages (`New Lead` and `EditInfo`) where the user can access by sliding. So it should be a `ViewPager`.

Based on the above information, I have to ask 2 questions.

1. While in `Home` screen, how user can click on the button and make the screen *slide* to access the next screen? When the user is in next screen (ex: To Do List) I prefer to let him slide right to go back to the `Home` screen. If this is not possible, at least pressing back button should do the sliding. How can I do this?
2. This contains application only one `FragmentActivity` and the `FragmentActivity` class contains the UI of Home screen. So where should I put the `ViewPager` of `Sales` screen? `Sales` is a `Fragment` and not `FragmentActivity`. So how can I facilitate it to navigate to NewLead and Edit Info pages via ViewPager?

Please help.

**UPDATE**

Since I am adviced to use a `Fragment` for `ViewPager` I would like to know whether it is best to create a seperate fragment for `ViewPager`. Below is the code. What is your advice?

```
public class ViewPagerManager extends Fragment{

    private static final int ITEMS = 2;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyAdapter pageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leads_and_sales_handling);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pageAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }



private  class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position==0)
            {
                return new SalesInqury();
            }
            else
            {
                return new NewLead();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the animation used when you switch between the fragments from your home screen using the `android.animation` framework. Some more information can be found here:
[Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)

In the sales fragment you will have a `ViewPager` as you suggested and this `ViewPager` will contain 3 more `Fragments` one will be for Sales one will be for New Lead and one will be for Edit info. Hopefully that makes sense to you

Comment: No. 'Sales' class is Sales.java, 'New Lead' is NewLead.java and so on. ViewPager should be implemented in FragmentActivity, not in Fragment right? All those screens are Fragments.

Comment: You can use a ViewPager where ever you want. It doesn't have to necessarily be in a FragmentActivity. If you want Sales, New Lead and Edit Info to be part of a View Pager then they should be Fragments. You then create a ViewPager object and add your 3 fragments to it

Comment: Then should I create a separate Fragment to hold the viewpager? I have updated a sample code, please have a look.

Comment: Yes, what you have seems fine. Is it working ok? To make it easier for you could use a SlidePagerAdapter for your view pager. So viewPager.setAdapter(new SlidePagerAdapter(activity.getFragmentManager(), fragment1, fragment2, fragment3)

Comment: I don't know. It was a quick workout. I didn't check. Will let you know soon.

Comment: In my previous comment fragment1, fragment2, and fragment3 would be created by Fragment fragment1 = new SalesInquiry() etc