# FragmentActivity custom Fragment transition

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make some kind of transition on Fragments, and i am using default application skeleton in eclipse for creating FragmentActivity. I noticed other posts for specifying custom transition animation from xml, but it is being done on Transaction, and none is using FragmentActivity. (Which is btw much easier.)

I would like to know how to make custom transitions in FragmentActivity.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Somthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments) but for FragmentActivity.

MusicPlayerActivity.java

```
public class MusicPlayerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // init pager and set its adapter
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //other init code ...
}

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new MainFragment();
        case 1:
            return new AllSongsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new SettingsFragment();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    /**
     * Get title for supplied Fragment number.
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

    //other methods

}
```

activity_music_player.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MusicPlayerActivity$OptionsFragment" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MusicPlayerActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Comment: If you're 'transitioning' between fragments, but not using a fragment transaction on events, this leads me to assume you're using a `ViewPager` and a `FragmentAdapter`? Could you post some code + layout

Comment: Ok i will, i am using ViewPager btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in your comment, you're using a `ViewPager`. This is slightly different to performing an animation on a `FragmentTransaction`.

What you'll want to use is a `ViewPager.PageTransformer`. There are some details on how to do that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer)

Answer (score 0):

Question is not much clear to me. But i believe this may serve your purpose.

from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)

public void overridePendingTransition (int enterAnim, int exitAnim)

Added in API level 5
Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

As of JELLY_BEAN an alternative to using this with starting activities is to supply the desired animation information through a ActivityOptions bundle to {@link #startActivity(Intent, Bundle) or a related function. This allows you to specify a custom animation even when starting an activity from outside the context of the current top activity.

Parameters
enterAnim   A resource ID of the animation resource to use for the incoming activity. Use 0 for no animation.
exitAnim    A resource ID of the animation resource to use for the outgoing activity. Use 0 for no animation.

Comment: Yep that is what all other posts said and definetly not what i want. I have 3 Fragments inside FragmentActivity and i want to change theirs transitions in between. I don't have any Transactions in code, everything is managed by FragmentActivity. I want to animate transition between Fragments not animation on launching and finishing activity.