# How to apply a fade-in/fade-out animation when replacing a fragment

Tags: android

I am  replacing a fragment with another fragment. I want the first fragment to disappear with a fade-out effect and second fragment to appear with fade-in effect. How is this done?

Comment: Do you know how to make the animations?

Comment: yes in xml file and load into activity

Comment: use ANIMATOR --- not Animation! use android.R.ANIMATOR.fade_in , DON'T use android.R.ANIM.fade_in - it has behavior BUGS

Answer (score 66):

With addition to @MD code

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,
                R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

and When you Pop Fragment then apply animation like:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);

ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);      
ft.commit();
```

and XML for fadeIn

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

and XML for fadeOut

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: You don't really need to create xml for base animations. Use default the ones : `setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);`

Comment: @Nexen yeah.. but if u notice M D's comment the guy asked for xml file code.

Comment: Use ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out); instead of ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_int);. First parameter is enter second parameter is exit.

Comment: @Nexen its not true . you can't use `anim` instead of `animator` . you can only use animator defaults for Fragment Transactions like this : `(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);`

Comment: use this default : `setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);`

Comment: `setCustomAnimations` can be used with four arguments like `setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);` to set animations when popping the back stack

Comment: @Qadeer Hussain accept this as the correct answer, please

Comment: Note the order matters: you must call the `setCustomAnimations` before you call `add` or `replace`

Answer (score 14):

When you Push a `Fragment` then apply animation like:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in,
                R.anim.fade_out);
ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

and When you Pop `Fragment` then apply animation like:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);

ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragment);      
ft.commit();
```

Hope this works for you.

**Update:** For more information go to

1. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/implement-animation-in.html
2. [Animate the transition between fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)

Comment: can your give the xml file code because its not working in my case

Comment: ok its working for me but i want when first frame fade in then second fade out after some time

Comment: @QadeerHussain change the order as per your requirement

Comment: thanks but only problem is i want when first fade-in fade-out start after some time for example if fade in duration 3000 then fade-out start after 3000 ms time

Comment: ```.setCustomAnimation``` must be set before ```.replace()``` otherwise won't work

Answer (score 6):

It is worth adding that setCustomAnimations can also have 4 arguments:

```
FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations (int enter, 
                                         int exit, 
                                         int popEnter, 
                                         int popExit)
```

> Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are
>   entering and exiting in this transaction. The popEnter and popExit
>   animations will be played for enter/exit operations specifically when
>   popping the back stack.