# Adding Custom Fragment Animations In Xamarin

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, xamarin

I am attempting to create a custom version of the Navigation Drawer using fragments. The issue that occurs is that while I am using the Xamarin Support Library v4, `Resource.Animation` slide animations throw an error of `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate` and I am unable to add my own animations because there is no Animation folder. When I try to create one, it gives me an error of `Invalid resource directory name: "animation".` How can I add my own animations to my project?

Comment: Try to call (in `res/`) the folder `anim` instead of `animation`.

Comment: Both `res` and `anim` don't exist. I have a folder called `Resources` and no animation folder under it, just drawables, layouts and whatnot.

Comment: In [the docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/graphics_and_animation/) in **View Animations** section, it says: "*The animation XML files will be stored in the /Resources/anim directory of a Xamarin.Android project*".

Comment: Ugh, thank you. I tried adding `Anim` before but it threw an error. Seems like its case sensitive and only accepts `anim`.

Comment: Did this solve also the `Unknown animator name: translate` error?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'll just have to use `objectAnimator`s instead of a `translate`.

Comment: See the link from the docs, and in the same section, you have a simple topic to create a set animation in xml and use it dynamically with `LoadAnimation()`. This is exactly the same with `translate`. Don't understand why you need an `ObjectAnimator` rather than this simplest way.

Comment: The reason I have to use an `objectAnimator` is because all `translate ` mentions in my code throw an error when those animations are run.

Comment: Then, can you share your files which cause these errors? Someone could help but it might be difficult without what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not unique to Xamarin.  It is a general issue in the Android framework.  You have to be careful about "Animator" versus "Animation."  See Nurik's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments?lq=1) for more info.