# How to make animation for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, animation, screen, screen-resolution, objectanimator

I need to make slide in and slide out animation for changing fragment. My animation slide out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="801"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

Fragment disappears before leaving screen on devices with higher resolution. Is it possibility to make animation for different screen sizes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This seemed to work for others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4936159/3249477). Didn't work for me however, had to animate with `Animation` manually.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did the YFraction method work for you?