# Setting animator xml values dynamically

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction, objectanimator

I am developing a turn based game, and there are 2 game boards, and when i want to switch between the 2 gameboards, i use a sliding animation. But here comes the problem. 
I have 4 animator xml files, in-right, out-right, in-left, out-left. 
here is one of them:

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="1000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

The sliding is working, but i test this game on an emulator with 1280px height (and the game is running in landscape mode),
at the end of the slide, there is a 280px wide part, that isn't sliding, just hiding at the end of the sliding animation.
When i set the valuefrom value to 2000, it is better, because the two board are not fading the other, but in this case there is a 720 px wide black area.

Do you know, how can i set these values dynamically based on the actual screen size? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate the transition between fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments) specifically check the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the factoring methods of `ObjectAnimator`.

Example:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetObject, "x", 0.f, 1000.f);
anim.setDuration(300);
anim.start();
```

You can get the metrics of the display or size of the Views programmatically with code like

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

View view = ...;
view.getHeight();
```

See:

- [ObjectAnimator factory method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#ofFloat(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20float...))
- [Property Animation tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)