# Animate Fragment without xml

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-fragments, objectanimator

I am looking for a way to do animate a fragment's transition without using xml.

The typical way to animate a fragment is to pass a xml animator along with the fragment to `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` (as an example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936159/1290264)

Instead, I'd like to send `setCustomAnimations` an `ObjectAnimator` to be applied to the fragment, but sadly this is not an option.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to add the `Animator`.

It is achieved by overriding the fragment's `onCreateAnimator` method before adding it to the fragmentManager. As an example, to slide the animation in and out during transition you can do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = new MyFragment(){
            @Override
            public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)
            {
                Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);

                Animator animator = null;
                if(enter){
                   animator = 
                     ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translationX", (float) size.x, 0);
                } else {
                   animator = 
                     ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translationX", 0, (float) size.x);
                }

                animator.setDuration(500);
                return animator;
            }
        }

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

P.S. this answer is thanks to a post in question section of [this forum](http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/).