# Navigation drawer lag

Tags: android, navigation, lag, drawer

The navigation drawer lags every time I open a new activity. I looked on Google for a solution and I found out that I can solve it by delaying the new activity with a Handler. I experimented a little bit but got nowhere.

Some code pieces from MainActivity.java:

```
 public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {

            case 2:
                fragment = new FragmentZero();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new FragmentZero();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                break;
            case 10:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                break;
            case 11:
                fragment = new FragmentZero();
                break;
            case 12:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                break;
            case 14:
                fragment = new FragmentZero();
                break;
            case 15:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                break;
            case 16:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

and

```
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
                SelectItem(position);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can bundle case statements like so to make your code more compact. See the SwitchDemo2  piece [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but as you said it's not for my question.

Comment: That's why I added it as a comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your activity create a handler and initialize it in your on create method

```
private Handler mHandler;
mHandler = new Handler();
```

then change your drawer item click listener to this.

```
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,
                            long id) {
        if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  SelectItem(position);;
              }
            }, 250);  
        }
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

and change SelectItem method to this

```
 public void SelectItem(int possition) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch (possition) {

        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentZero();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new FragmentZero();
            break;
        case 9:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 10:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        case 11:
            fragment = new FragmentZero();
            break;
        case 12:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 14:
            fragment = new FragmentZero();
            break;
        case 15:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 16:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
    frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
    setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
}
```

Comment: I got it working, I've set the timer to 300 but I still don't like the way it works.When I press a button from the drawer's panel, it slides nice and slow and then the activity comes like a flash, instant.

Comment: You can animate transitions between fragments to help smoothen everythng out. Check out this question for more info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments