# Transition a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-transitions

What is the simplest way to transition a fragment in Android?

I'm striving for a single line solution.

What I tried:

I added a transition xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionManager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <fade xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</transitionManager>
```

And I'm using the following code to apply the above transition:

```
 EmailInfoFragment instanceFragment=
                    (EmailInfoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.emailInfoFrag);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(1);
            instanceFragment.whatToShow(result);
```

I know that the code above is completely wrong, but this is something I'm trying to achieve, apply a very simple transition to a fragment on screen...

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int%29) is what you are looking for. also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936159/3916856).

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, EmailInfoFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
```

work for you?

It switches from the currently active fragment to a new one aquired by `EmailInfoFragment.newInstance()`, which might aswell be `new EmailInfoFragment()` but seems to be used quite often and I kinda learned it that way...