# Dynamic scale animation on replacing Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to replace a fragment with animation but it has to be dynamic every time, i.e. it will start from the point where I will click on the screen but `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` method uses the predefined animation defined in anim folder like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
```

I create object of `ScaleAnimation` to meet my need like this:

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(fromX,ToX,fromY,toY,pivitX,pivotY);
animation.setDuration(500);
```

`fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` method does not accept `scaleAnimation` it only accepts int. So how to attain dynamic animation while replacing fragment.

Comment: have you got answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom animation sets and use them.

Create an .xml file and put it in 'res/anim' folder and then use its resource id in code:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.your_animation, R.anim.your_animation);
```

Here is and example of the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-10%p"
    android:toYDelta="1%p"/>

<scale
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.98"
    android:toYScale="0.98"/>

<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-10%p"
    android:fromYDelta="1%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="5%p"/>

<scale
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXScale="0.98"
    android:fromYScale="0.98"
    android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:toYScale="0.9"/>
</set>
```

Comment: This is possible i know but i want to achieve dynamic animation. I want to start animation from the point where i clicked on the screen

Comment: This will lead to ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate```. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932462/4279747) post for further informations.

Answer (score 2):

Fragment animation with `translate` tag in XML will not work via `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()`. This will lead to `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932462/4279747) post for further informations.

Try to use `objectAnimator` instead. You can achieve a scale animation with an animator xml like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="200dp" android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0.0" android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0.5" android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0.5" android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

The key value is `android:propertyName` where you have to set `scaleX` and/or `scaleY`. Now you can use this xml with `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()`.