# Vertical transition between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to implement application where top part of the second activity is always visible on the bottom of the screen. When user swipes up this activity, then it occupies full screen (with nice scroll up animation). This activity is again hidden when user swipes screen down.

How can I implement something like this?

[Please check sample picture from another here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJNlI.png)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments

Comment: I would like to display two activities at once (one partially at the bottom and another one in the background) and when user swipes on the bottom activity, then this activity slides up.

Comment: You can't have two activities active at same time: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle so for your layout use Fragments