# STAMINA mode breaks fragment loading with custom animations

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, sony-xperia

This code is working as expected on all devices except Sony devices with activated STAMINA mode:

```
int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();    
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(backStackCount == 0? R.animator.noanim : R.animator.slide_in,
                        R.animator.zoom_out, R.animator.zoom_in, backStackCount == 0? R.animator.noanim : R.animator.slide_out)
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, String.valueOf(backStackCount))
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().toString())
                .commit();
```

With STAMINA mode the first Fragment is loaded normally, but the next one does not show up at all (the screen remains black). If I comment out the `setCustomAnimations` method, the transaction works as expected. What is going on here, how to get the transaction working with activated STAMINA mode?

R.animator.slide_in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
                    android:valueFrom="1.0"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:propertyName="xFraction"
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**EDIT**: solved by myself, see below

Answer (score 0):

I used [Roman Nurik's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936159/321106) for animating the `Fragments`. If the STAMINA mode is activated, the animations are disabled and the `setXFraction` method is called only once with the end value of the animation. The width of the `View` is 0 at this moment, so it's never going to be placed at the right position.

The solution is to delay the placement until the layout is finished:

```
public void setXFraction(float xFraction) {
    this.xFraction = xFraction;
    post(() -> {
        final int width = getWidth();
        setX((width > 0) ? (this.xFraction * width) : -9999);
    });
}
```